# How do you determine a processing time in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm new to Python, and confused by the date/time documentation.  I want to compute the time that it takes to perform a computation.

In java, I would write:

```
long timeBefore = System.currentTimeMillis();
doStuff();
long timeAfter = System.currentTimeMillis();
elapsed time = timeAfter - timeBefore;
```

I'm sure it's even easier in Python. Can anyone help?

Comment: Specifically, what *Python* code are you looking at?

Comment: I wasn't looking at Python code, I was preparing to write it.  By the way, I'm intrigued by your Building Skills in Python book, I'll be checking it out.

Comment: related: [Measure time elapsed in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7370801/4279)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Equivalent in python would be:

```
>>> import time
>>> tic = time.clock()
>>> toc = time.clock()
>>> toc - tic
```

If you are trying to find the best performing method then you should probably have a look at [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html).

Comment: indeed, prob `clock` is better for this sort of measurements.

Comment: Thanks for providing the equivalent.  I'll have to look into `timeit` in the future, but for my current small exercise this will be sufficient.

Comment: Note that `time.clock` doesn't do the same on all platforms. More notably, on unix it returns processor time, not clock time.

Comment: `time.clock()` is deprecated since Python 3.3 and prints a warning since Python 3.7. The recommended functions are now `time.process_time()` and `time.perf_counter()`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.clock

Comment: Can this answer please be updated for python >=3.3? Please replace time.clock() with .perf_counter() or .process_time()

Answer (score 40):

Building on and updating a number of earlier responses (thanks: SilentGhost, nosklo, Ramkumar) a simple portable timer would use `timeit`'s `default_timer()`:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> tic=timeit.default_timer()
>>> # Do Stuff
>>> toc=timeit.default_timer()
>>> toc - tic #elapsed time in seconds
```

This will return the elapsed wall clock (real) time, not CPU time. And as described in the [`timeit` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) chooses the most precise available real-world timer depending on the platform.

ALso, beginning with Python 3.3 this same functionality is available with the [`time.perf_counter`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) performance counter. Under 3.3+ timeit.default_timer() refers to this new counter.

For more precise/complex performance calculations, `timeit` includes more sophisticated calls for automatically timing small code snippets including averaging run time over a defined set of repetitions.

Answer (score 16):

You can implement two `tic()` and `tac()` functions, where `tic()` captures the time which it is called, and `tac()` prints the time difference since `tic()` was called. Here is a short implementation:

```py
import time

_start_time = time.time()

def tic():
    global _start_time 
    _start_time = time.time()

def tac():
    t_sec = round(time.time() - _start_time)
    (t_min, t_sec) = divmod(t_sec,60)
    (t_hour,t_min) = divmod(t_min,60) 
    print('Time passed: {}hour:{}min:{}sec'.format(t_hour,t_min,t_sec))
```

Now in your code you can use it as:

```
tic()
do_some_stuff()
tac()
```

and it will, for example, output:

```
Time passed: 0hour:7min:26sec
```

### See also:

- Python's datetime library: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html
- Python's time library: https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html

Comment: Isn't it tic/toc? :-)

Comment: He's probably french :)

Answer (score 14):

For Python 3.3 and later [`time.process_time()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.process_time) is very nice:

```
import time

t = time.process_time()
#do some stuff
elapsed_time = time.process_time() - t
```

Comment: Note this ignores any `time.sleep()` time delays in the code, I just tried testing it with `time.sleep()` for a minute and got quite confused! E.g. if you want to repeat the process at precise time intervals like webscraping, can measure elapsed_time then add on appropriate `time.sleep()` delay

Comment: Spoke too soon, Actually I just used selenium package to open website login, send message, can see it's taking 20 seconds or more just for selenium to fill out the message in text box, but get 0.125 as the elapsed time from `process_time()` before getting the URL to time at end typing message, not sure what's going on, docs mentions time.sleep() delays ignored by process_time, but filling the box is normal processing time surely, sending several send_keys() calls from selenium to do this.

Comment: @WillCroxford I encountered similar with process_time(). time() gave a more accurate number for the wait I experienced before my functions executed.

Answer (score 6):

Use timeit. http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html

Answer (score 2):

I also got a requirement to calculate the process time of some code lines. So I tried the approved answer and I got this warning.

```sh
DeprecationWarning: time.clock has been deprecated in Python 3.3 and will be removed from Python 3.8: use time.perf_counter or time.process_time instead
```

So python will [remove time.clock()](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/13270) from [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/index.html). You can see more about it from issue [#13270](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/13270). This warning suggest two function instead of [time.clock()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.clock). In the documentation also mention about this warning in-detail in [time.clock()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.clock) section.

> Deprecated since version 3.3, will be removed in version 3.8: The behaviour of this function depends on the platform: use perf_counter() or process_time() instead, depending on your requirements, to have a well defined behaviour.

Let's look at in-detail both functions.

---

- **[time.perf_counter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter)**

> Return the value (in fractional seconds) of a performance counter, i.e. a clock with the highest available resolution to measure a short duration. It does include time elapsed during sleep and is system-wide. The reference point of the returned value is undefined, so that only the difference between the results of two calls is valid.
>
> New in version 3.3.
>
> Changed in version 3.10: On Windows, the function is now system-wide.

So if you want it as `nanoseconds`, you can use [time.perf_counter_ns()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter_ns) and if your code consist with [time.sleep(secs)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep), it will also count. Ex:-

```py
import time


def func(x):
    time.sleep(5)
    return x * x


lst = [1, 2, 3]
tic = time.perf_counter()
print([func(x) for x in lst])
toc = time.perf_counter()
print(toc - tic)

# [1, 4, 9]
# 15.0041916 --> output including 5 seconds sleep time
```

---

- **[time.process_time()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.process_time)**

> Return the value (in fractional seconds) of the sum of the system and user CPU time of the current process. It does not include time elapsed during sleep. It is process-wide by definition. The reference point of the returned value is undefined, so that only the difference between the results of two calls is valid.
>
> Use process_time_ns() to avoid the precision loss caused by the float type.
>
> New in version 3.3.

So if you want it as `nanoseconds`, you can use [time.process_time_ns()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter_ns) and if your code consist with [time.sleep(secs)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep), it won't count. Ex:-

```py
import time


def func(x):
    time.sleep(5)
    return x * x


lst = [1, 2, 3]
tic = time.process_time()
print([func(x) for x in lst])
toc = time.process_time()
print(toc - tic)

# [1, 4, 9]
# 0.0 --> output excluding 5 seconds sleep time
```

---

**Please note both [time.perf_counter_ns()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter_ns) and [time.process_time_ns()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter_ns) come up with [Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3.7/index.html) onward.**

Answer (score 1):

```
python -m timeit -h
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is the time between two points in code (and it seems that's what you want) I have written `tic()` `toc()` functions ala Matlab's implementation. The basic use case is:

```
tic()

''' some code that runs for an interesting amount of time '''

toc()

# OUTPUT:
# Elapsed time is: 32.42123 seconds
```

Super, incredibly easy to use, a sort of fire-and-forget kind of code. It's available on Github's Gist https://gist.github.com/tyleha/5174230

Comment: `time.time()` is not monotonic and must not be used to measure time intervals

Comment: Interesting, you are correct. Glad to learn something new! Additionally, thanks for taking the time to dig up this 3 yr old answer, read through my Gist, downvote me, and yet not provide a suggestion of an alternative or an explanation why it's non-monotonic! For those of you who are looking to actually improve your code and learn, some research of my own suggests you should use [`time.monotonic`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0418/#time-monotonic), available in Python 3.3+ (which I now use). `time.time` is not monotonic because it relies on system time, which can be modified mid-run

Answer (score 1):

For some further information on how to determine the processing time, and a comparison of a few methods (some mentioned already in the answers of this post) - specifically, the difference between:

```
start = time.time()
```

versus the now obsolete ([as of 3.3, time.clock() is deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.clock))

```
start = time.clock()
```

see this other article on Stackoverflow here:

[Python - time.clock() vs. time.time() - accuracy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85451/python-time-clock-vs-time-time-accuracy)

If nothing else, this will work good:

```
start = time.time()

... do something

elapsed = (time.time() - start)
```