# Pygame, I am trying to make a timer

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I have created a game that has two cars who race each other by tapping buttons quicker than the other. So i want to make it where after the race ends it prints out how long it took for the winner of the race to make it to the finish line. I have tried using `pygame.time.get_ticks()` however that gives the time of how long since `pygame.init()` was called.

Comment: See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/measure-time-elapsed-in-python

Comment: Thank you, i will look over it and see how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pygame.time.get_ticks()`.

Set a start time and an end time and measure the difference:

```
import pygame as py
py.init()
clock = py.time.Clock()

start_time = py.time.get_ticks()
print "started at:",start_time

for i in xrange(0,30): #wait 1 second
    clock.tick(30)

end_time = py.time.get_ticks()
print "finished at:",end_time

time_taken = end_time-start_time
print "time taken:",time_taken
```

Comment: Thank you. i will try it. But what is the point of the `for` loop?

Comment: The for loop is simply waiting 1 second in the way a 30fps game would

Comment: Ohh okay. May i ask why that's useful?

Comment: It was to simulate a person taking around a seconds to finish the race.