# Using tensorflow, how do I find the time taken for an epoch during fitting?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am following along this tutorial, 
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification

When I fit the model using `model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5, verbose =1)`, the times are displayed in the python console.  I want to get the wall time of each epoch by using `time.clock()`.

I am assuming that when more epochs are added the fitting time increases linearly, but I want to graph this to be sure.

Besides fitting with 1 epoch, then 2 epochs, then 3 epochs, etc, how can I work out the training time (fitting time) for an increasing number of epochs?

Answer (score 4):

Using a custom callback you can plot the total time taken to fit certain epochs.

```
class timecallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self):
        self.times = []
        # use this value as reference to calculate cummulative time taken
        self.timetaken = time.clock()
    def on_epoch_end(self,epoch,logs = {}):
        self.times.append((epoch,time.clock() - self.timetaken))
    def on_train_end(self,logs = {}):
        plt.xlabel('Epoch')
        plt.ylabel('Total time taken until an epoch in seconds')
        plt.plot(*zip(*self.times))
        plt.show()
```

And then pass this as a callback to the model.fit function like this

```
timetaken = timecallback()
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5,callbacks = [timetaken])
```

This plots a graph at the end of training which shows the total time taken for the model to train upto a certain epoch from the start.

And if you want to plot the per epoch time. You can replace the on_train_end method with on_epoch_end.

```
def on_epoch_end(self,epoch,logs= {}):
    # same as the on_train_end function
```

Comment: Substitute time.clock() with time.process_time()
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49667496/336558

Answer (score 1):

Using a [custom callback](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_callback) definitely works but you must be careful of how you generate a timestamp. The recommended `time.clock()` [works differently on Windows vs UNIX systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37111678/time-clock-doesnt-return-time-properly) and may not generate the behavior that you want. Therefore, I recommend a tweak to the code others have recommended, using the built in tensorflow.timestamp() method ([documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/timestamp)). Note that this is a tensor object so if you'd like to plot the time as text, as I did, you'll need to extract the float value. I did so using `.numpy()` as this is an [EagerTensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

class timecallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self):
        self.times = []
        self.epochs = []
        # use this value as reference to calculate cummulative time taken
        self.timetaken = tf.timestamp()
    def on_epoch_end(self,epoch,logs = {}):
        self.times.append(tf.timestamp() - self.timetaken)
        self.epochs.append(epoch)
    def on_train_end(self,logs = {}):
        plt.xlabel('Epoch')
        plt.ylabel('Total time taken until an epoch in seconds')
        plt.plot(self.epochs, self.times, 'ro')
        for i in range(len(self.epochs)):
          j = self.times[i].numpy()
          if i == 0:
            plt.text(i, j, str(round(j, 3)))
          else:
            j_prev = self.times[i-1].numpy()
            plt.text(i, j, str(round(j-j_prev, 3)))
        plt.savefig(datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S") + ".png")
```

Then, when calling model fit:

```
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5,callbacks = [timecallback()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Good practice to use callbacks. How do we record the durations in the history?

Say we're using
`history = model.fit( ..., callbacks=[my_training_callback])`

What should I write into the definition of `my_training_callback`?
I'm tryin to do:

```
def my_training_callback(Callback):
    def __init__(self):
        mark = 0
        duration = 0
    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
        self.mark = time()
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        self.duration = time() - self.mark
```

It works ok, but I'm having trouble adding the `duration` value to the history.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to add the duration to the history.

The trick comes from the fact that the `logs` object passed to the methods of `Callback` is mutable, and is the same one that is passed to each callback... including the `History` object returned by `model.fit`.

So if you want the duration of each epoch in the history (as opposed to displayed on the screen or saved to a file as in the other answers), you have to add it to the `logs` object in your custom callback.

Example:

```py
import datetime
import tensorflow as tf
class TimestampCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, metric_name = "duration"):
        self.__epoch_start = None
        self.__metric_name = metric_name

    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
        self.__epoch_start = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        logs[self.__metric_name] = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - self.__epoch_start
```

You don't have to use `datetime` obviously. And if you have a callback that consumes the duration, make sure to put it **after** this callback in the callback list. Because `History` is called after every callback, it will always receive the duration.

Comment: This one spit some errors when I tried. It had some issues with the ```datetime.utcnow()``` math operation (I couldn't imagine why, but replacing ```datetime.utcnow()``` with ```tf.timestamp()``` made it work). Also, it didn't recognise the ```metric_name```. I set it *within* ```__init__``` as ```self.metric_name = ...```. Now it appears to work for me; at least when I tested it with this example model: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate

Comment: That's weird, math operations between `datetime` objects are as old as the module itself... As for the `metric_name` field, my bad, it seems I forgot to set it in the code example. I'll edit the post.