# Most efficient way to get count of bigrams with specific frequency

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk, processing-efficiency, coding-efficiency

I'm trying to retrieve a list of bigrams with a specific frequency (`i`).

I've managed to come up with two ways to do it and I am wondering which would be the most efficient. I first create a list of bigrams `bg1` then use the `nltk.FreqDist` method:

```
import nltk
from nltk import FreqDist
from nltk import bigrams

#setup data
from nltk.book import text1

#keep only alpha words / remove punctuation
alphlist = [w for w in list(text1) if w.isalpha()]
#create bigrams list
bg1 = bigrams(alphlist)

#create freqdist object
fdist1 = nltk.FreqDist(bg1)
```

Approach one uses the `most_common` sort first:

```
for obj in fdist1.most_common():
  if obj[1] == i:
    print(obj)
```

Approach two parses `fdist1` directly:

```
for obj in fdist1:
  if fdist1[obj] == i:
    print(obj, fdist1[obj])
```

Which approach is better and why?

Comment: Please try not to wipe out existing edits when adding more information to the question

Comment: Hi Jon. Apologies if I did that. I am completely new here. I honestly didn't know you were editing. Is there some way of knowing that someone else is editing at the same time as me? I'll do whatever is the right thing once I know how. :-)

Comment: #2 should be most efficient, since sorting is O(nlogn) and simply inspecting the elements directly is O(n). With that said, you're in the best position to answer this since you can time both methods while we can only theorize. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/measure-time-elapsed-in-python