# Jupyter Notebook time profiling

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython-magic

So I installed jupyter notebook through anaconda and I am working on python 3 kernel.

I am trying to do Time profiling using `%time` magic command as show [here](http://pynash.org/2013/03/06/timing-and-profiling/)
The problem is that it only prints the **Wall Time** not the **CPU Time**

using `%time` or `%%time` does not help

- `%time` prints the *wall time* for the **first line** only
- `%%time` prints the *wall time* for the **whole cell**

I am not sure if there any specif config to print the CPU time

**EDIT**

To clarify using `%%time` should print two metrics for the *whole cell*

- **Metric 1**: CPU Times
- **Metric 2**: wall time

my problem is that I only get wall time not CPU time.

You may check this [link](http://pynash.org/2013/03/06/timing-and-profiling/) on what is the expected output for `%%time`

Comment: you want `%timeit` for consistent timings this will run the line of code multiple times and return the average, `%%timeit` gives the time for the cell

Comment: @EdChum not really .. what I want is the CPU times which should be printed using `%time` .. have a look at the link above to see what I mean

Comment: Ah right, I see your issue, I don't know if you can get the specific cpu time, rather you can get the system and cpu time: https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.process_time, see related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/measure-time-elapsed-in-python. I don't see anything built-in as a magic command in ipython

Comment: @EdChum well I see what you are trying to do, however I am sure magic command `%%time` shall show the CPU times. I actually managed to do it as it seem a windows issue. Running on Ubuntu gave the me the desired result

Comment: That's interesting I didn't think there would be a behavioural difference between ubuntu and windows. Please post an answer as I think this would be useful for others to know

Comment: @EdChum actually I faced a lot of issues where there was a behavioral difference between Windows and Ubuntu. One was related to `concurrent.futures` which kept failing on windows but works fine on Ubuntu. Another was related to running the library `mrocklin/fakestockdata` which prints no results on windows but works fine on Ubuntu.

Comment: @EdChum anyhow I added an answer as advised. Thanks for ur help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So it seems that my issue was in the environment itself.

Switching from Windows to Ubuntu actually helped me print the *CPU times*.

Comment: maintaining windows OS , is it possible to print  CPU usage, hope you resolve the issue, I spent a lot of time on that but, nothing works!!

Comment: @ikbelbenabdessamad I honestly don't know. I tried everything back then but nothing worked for Windows unfortunately. There seems to be a behavioral difference between Windows and Ubuntu, read the comments above for more details.

Comment: @ikbelbenabdessamad you can now use Linux-based systems on Windows thanks to WSL. Check this article for more details: https://fireship.io/lessons/windows-10-for-web-dev/