# %%time Does not return CPU time on Windows in Jupyter notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipython-magic

I am using `%%time` in Jupyter-notebook to measure run time of my Python code. The problem is that it prints only the `Wall time` on **Windows** but works fine on **Ubuntu**.

Is it possible to get the `CPU time` on **Windows** as well?

I am using Windows 10, Python 3.6 Anaconda release.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jupyter Notebook time profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089465/jupyter-notebook-time-profiling)

Comment: The other questions' answer is just stating that it doesn't work on Windows. There is no real solution.

Comment: @Enra, yes I edited the subject and body to reflect the specific issue and retracted my flag

Answer (score 0):

it is imposssible to use it in windows, the official documents says below

> Note that under Win32, system time is always reported as 0, since it can not be measured.

[reference](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-time)