# Is faster to compare int values or strings?

Tags: python

I have a series of values in a file and I'm iterating on them.
Is it faster to run:

```
if FTB == "0":  
  do something
```

or

```
if int(FTB) > 0:  
  do something
```

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/measure-time-elapsed-in-python you can check it by yourself easily

Comment: Why don't you test it and report back with the results ;)

Comment: Benchmark using the `timeit` module and see which one is faster. Do you really need that level of optimization?

Comment: I think this is called "premature optimization"

Comment: When you benchmark this, don't forget to include the overhead of converting to or from the types, if that's what ou are considering.

Answer (score 2):

Simply using the `%timeit` function in IPython:

```
FTB = 0

%timeit if FTB == 0: pass
10000000 loops, best of 3: 47 ns per loop

FTB = '0'

%timeit if int(FTB) == 0: pass
The slowest run took 9.47 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 231 ns per loop
```

If you're planning to convert string -> integer on-the-fly using `int()`, then it looks like you're losing out on (relatively) quite a bit of speed. Comparisons involving `FTB` as a `int` to begin with are almost 80% faster than comparisons coercing a string `FTB` to integer.

Perhaps your original question was whether simply comparing already-typed objects (like something already an `int` or `str` and not needing type conversion) was different, speed-wise, in the case of strings and integers. In that case, for completeness:

```
FTB = '0'

%timeit if FTB == '0': pass
10000000 loops, best of 3: 49.9 ns per loop

FTB = 0

%timeit if str(FTB) == '0': pass
The slowest run took 8.62 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 233 ns per loop
```

More sampling may be required, but naively it's tough to say there's a significant speed difference comparing `str` to `str` versus `int` to `int`. The biggest cost is the cost of calling either the `int()` or `str()` function to change types.

Answer (score 0):

I am late for the party but here is a simple code that shows that there is almost no difference in python.

Also what may comes to my mind is that integers are limited by the lengt while a string can be any size (until you are out of memory) that's why I am increasing the size.

```
import time


theinteger = 2147483647
thestring = "2147483647"

stringtime = []
integertime = []

for i in range(0,99999):
    t0 = time.time()
    if thestring == "2147483647":
        print("hello")
    t1 = time.time();
    stringtime.append(t1 - t0)


    t0 = time.time()
    if theinteger == 2147483647:
        print("hello")
    t1 = time.time();
    integertime.append(t1 - t0)

    theinteger = theinteger + 1;
    thestring = str(theinteger)

print("time for string: " + str(sum(stringtime)/len(stringtime)))
print("time for integer: " + str(sum(integertime)/len(integertime)))
```

Comment: Your timings include the call to `print` which will *dwarf* the actual comparison by a couple orders of magnitude.

Comment: Sure but they are in both, so they get added in both times.

Answer (score -1):

Integers are faster to compare because on the CPU it is just one operation. Strings are a representation of an array of characters. To compare a String you have to compare earch item in the array until you find a difference. So this are much more operations to compare the whole String.
But the difference is in the range of a couple of nano seconds.

Comment: Except Python integer objects are *boxed* and of arbitrary size. The real cost here is the `int()` call, which converts a string to a new object (Python has no casting).