# How to add python timer

Tags: python

I'm making a controller for my jacuzzi with a raspberry pi. I have the code below, but whenIi push a button the script sleeps. I want it to keep running (check if other buttons are pressed) but want when button1 is pressed the relays opens for xx time.

Does anybody know how to?

```
import  RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)#Button1
GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)#Button2
GPIO.setup(1, GPIO.OUT) #motor relais

GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)#Buffertanksensor laag
GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)#Buffertanksensor hoog
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT) #3-wegklep relais
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT) #Buffertank full LED

#Button press for on/off  jet motor
while True:
    Button1 = GPIO.input(21)
    if (Button1 == False):
        print("Button press ")
        GPIO.output(1, 0)
        time.sleep(5)
        GPIO.output(1, 1)

    Button2 = GPIO.input(26)
    if (Button2 == False):
        print("Button press 2 ")
        GPIO.output(1, 0)
        time.sleep(20)
        GPIO.output(1, 1)

#Buffertank

    Sensor1 = GPIO.input(6)
    if (Sensor1 == False):
        print("Sensor laag actief")
        GPIO.output(25, 1)
        time.sleep(10)
        GPIO.output(25, 0)

    Sensor2 = GPIO.input(5)
    if (Sensor2 == False):
        print("Sensor hoog actief")
        GPIO.output(7, 0)
time.sleep(0.3)
```

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/measure-time-elapsed-in-python#7370824

Comment: don't use `sleep()` in tkinter. Use `after()` instead. It will be what you are looking for.

Comment: don't use `sleep()` in your jacuzzi ! sorry... loved the catchphrase