# Any ideas on how to track time taken?

Tags: python, pycharm

So, recently i've been interested in checking out how long it takes for someone or something to finish a task. (For example, how long it takes for someone to answer a prompt) So i've been thinking of how to track the time taken. I've thought of it before, but failed miserably and didn't try again until now. [This is what I tried before](https://pastebin.com/zazVtZZD), but it didn't work properly for obvious reasons (because `time.sleep` waits for a few seconds but doesn't tell you how long it took). (I'm trying to track someone's time, not dictate it) But recently, I thought of a system that works but isn't precise. [It goes something like this](https://pastebin.com/RQPKyZ9D), and it works, but it's not precise. Because if I take 5.37 seconds to answer the prompt, it shows that I took 5 seconds. It works, but I was just wondering if it was possible to be more precise..

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/measure-time-elapsed-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use datetime:

```
import datetime

before = datetime.datetime.now()

a = input()

after = datetime.datetime.now()

diff = after-before

diff.total_seconds()
```

Returns:

```
2.426867
```