# Why is the difference in Timestamp of a same code snippet in python with opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I wanted to find out the amount of time taken for a module or function to execute. I have used two methods mentioned below, but the time taken in each case is not the same for the same function. Why?

```
import time
from timeit import default_timer as timer

start=timer()
ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
end=timer()
print("Time Taken by Binary Thresh1 = {}".format(end-start))

e1=cv2.getTickCount()
ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
e2=cv2.getTickCount()
t=(e2-e1)/cv2.getTickFrequency()
print("Time Taken by Binary Thresh2 = {}".format(t))
```

Output

```
Time Taken by Binary Thresh1 = 0.00017630465444318233
Time Taken by Binary Thresh2 = 3.005609493620777e-05
```

Kindly let me what is the reason , or anything wrong in the code?

Comment: Your computer may have had to do more on other tasks at one point. It is never guaranteed that a function runs in the same amount of time every time. It depends on the environment...

Comment: Please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/measure-time-elapsed-in-python

Comment: I'm not sure how you can measure anything with that script, considering there are at least two syntax errors.

Comment: maybe the precision/resolution of the different timers?  Maybe overhead? MAYBE memory allocation for thresh1 image only during the first threshold computation? Did you try to create a new variable for the 2nd threshold computation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely a problem of trying to measure too little and then seeing an effect of your PC doing *other things*

It would be worth having a read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array) SO post which may give you some background info.

As for measuring what you want to measure better I would suggest doing it 100 or 1000 times and measuring the total time. You can then work backwards to see how long each attempt took or create an average time.

Also see [here](https://marcobonzanini.com/2015/01/05/my-python-code-is-slow-tips-for-profiling/) for tips on profiling Python code.