# Simpson's Rule Takes Forever to Run in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, integral, simpsons-rule

I've written the following function for estimating the definite integral of a function with Simpson's Rule:

```
def fnInt(func, a, b):
    if callable(func) and type(a) in [float] and type(b) in [float]:
        if a > b:
            return -1 * fnInt(func, b, a)
        else:
            y1 = nDeriv(func)
            y2 = nDeriv(y1)
            y3 = nDeriv(y2)
            y4 = nDeriv(y3)
            f = lambda t: abs(y4(t))
            k = f(max(f, a, b))
            n = ((1 / 0.00001) * k * (b - a) ** 5 / 180) ** 0.25
            if n > 0:
                n = math.ceil(n) if math.ceil(n) % 2 == 0 else math.ceil(n) + 1
            else:
                n = 2
            x = (b - a) / n
            ans = 0
            for i in range(int((n - 4) / 2 + 1)):
                ans += (x / 3) * (4 * func(a + x * (2 * i + 1)) + 2 * func(a + x * (2 * i + 2)))
            ans += (x / 3) * (func(a) + 4 * func(a + x * (n - 1)) + func(b))
            return ans
    else:
        raise TypeError('Data Type Error')
```

It seems, however, that whenever I try to use this function, it takes forever to produce an output. Is there a way that I can rewrite this code in order to take up less time?

Comment: Have you ever tried profiling, to see what is taking most of the time?

Comment: Hi Michael, you might want to put this Q into the following:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you are doing this for a "serious" purpose rather than to teach yourself Python, you should use [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.simps.html) instead of writing it yourself.  Their implementation uses NumPy arrays and will be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

As one of the comments mentioned, profiling the code will show you the slowdowns.  Perhaps `nDeriv` is slow.  If you don't have a profiling tool, you can put `time()` calls around each section of code and print the results.  More info here: [Measure time elapsed in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/measure-time-elapsed-in-python)

So, if the slowdown ends up being in your `for` loop, here are a few things you can try:

1. Python might be computing the loop condition every iteration:

   `for i in range(int((n - 4) / 2 + 1)):`

calculate `int((n - 4) / 2 + 1)` once before the loop.

2. Don't recalculate stuff inside the loops that doesn't change.  For example, `x / 3` is going to be recalculated every loop iteration, but it never changes.  Do it before the loop starts.

Likewise, you're doing `2 * i` twice every loop iteration.

3. Addition is faster than multiplication.  The func arguments could be re-written as:

   `xi = x * i
   a1 = a + xi + xi + x
   a2 = a1 + x`

and then taking it a step further, you could also re-do `xi` as an accumulator.  That is, start with `x = 0`, then every iteration simply `x += x`

4. This is probably obvious, but if `func()` is difficult to calculate, this function will be exponentially slow.

Python may be doing a lot of simpler optimizations for you, so these may not help, but just wanted to share some ideas.