# python timedelta microseconds always 0

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I'm trying to measure a difference bewteen two timestamps in microseconds. In the timedelta object I can't only get milisecond, everything beyond milisecond seems to be rounded up.

```
import datetime

a = datetime.datetime.now()
_ = [i for i in range(123452)]  #just to spend some time
b = datetime.datetime.now()

print ((b-a).microseconds)
```

returns: 5000

Note: Using Python 3.6 on Windows 7

Comment: The resolution of `datetime.now()` is platform-dependent. You should add on which platform you are using Python.

Comment: You should use [`time.perf_counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) to measure something like this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I measure elapsed time in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/how-do-i-measure-elapsed-time-in-python)