# How to know how long GEKKO took to solve my model?

Tags: python, gekko

How can I get an output from GEKKO on how long it took to solve my model? I know based off of [Measure time elapsed in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/measure-time-elapsed-in-python) that I can get my code to print the total time taken to run my code but I do not know how to isolate the solver time.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import time
start = time.time()
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
x = m.Var(value=0)
y = m.Var(value=1)
m.Equations([x + 2*y==0, x**2+y**2==1])
s1 = time.time()
m.solve(disp=True)
e1 = time.time()
print([x.value[0],y.value[0]])
end = time.time()
print('Total Elapsed: ' + str(end-start))
print('Solver Time 1: ' + str(e1-s1))
```

Solver Time 1 is listed as `0.18468` sec but this is different than the IPOPT reported time of `0.0156` sec. How can I programmatically get the solver reported time?

```
EXIT: Optimal Solution Found.

 The solution was found.

 The final value of the objective function is  0.

 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  IPOPT (v3.12)
 Solution time  :  0.0156 sec
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the solver reported time with `m.options.SOLVETIME` such as:

```py
print('Solver Time 2: ', m.options.SOLVETIME)
```

`Solver Time 1` includes the setup and solution transfer. You can speed up the total time by not displaying the solver output with `disp=False` and solving locally instead of on a remote server with `remote=False`. A local solve generally reduces the amount of time it takes to send to a server and retrieve a solution but there are fewer solver options with a local solve.