# How can I know interpretation time of my python program?

Tags: python, time

So how can I  interpretation time of my python program?
For example in JavaScript we have console.time() and console.timeEnd()

Comment: The documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html). there is a `time` module and a `timeit` module. The `timeit` is used to time execution speeds. Also a `profile` module to profile execution speeds of pieces of your process.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Measure time elapsed in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/measure-time-elapsed-in-python)

Comment: There is also the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/timeit.html) module if you want to benchmark specific code snippets