# How to convert a for loop with np.column_stack/np.row_stack into a generator

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, generator

I have the following code:

```
from itertools import product
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from operator import mul
import numpy as np

lst = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
arr = np.array(lst)

flat = np.ravel(arr).tolist()
lst = (list(a) for a in product(flat, repeat=2))
results = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(mul)(x, y) for x, y in lst)

rows = arr.shape[0]
cols = arr.shape[1]

arr3d = np.array(results).reshape(rows, cols, rows, cols)

def stacking():
    final_arr = np.empty((1, cols*cols))   # Initialize final_arr
    for i in range(0,rows):
        first_block = arr3d[i,0]   # Initialize first_block
        for j in range(1,cols):
            first_block = np.column_stack((first_block, arr3d[i,j]))
        final_arr = np.row_stack((final_arr, first_block))
    yield np.delete(final_arr, 0, axis=0)

next(stacking())
```

I wish to convert both the for loops (i's and j's) to a generator. When I tried to do this for the j loop:

```
def stacking():
    final_arr = np.empty((1, cols*cols))   # Initialize final_arr
    for i in range(0,rows):
        first_block = arr3d[i,0]   # Initialize first_block
        first_block = (np.column_stack((first_block, arr3d[i,j])) for j in range(1,cols))
        final_arr = np.row_stack((final_arr, first_block))
    yield np.delete(final_arr, 0, axis=0)

next(stacking())
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-ba342fd13303> in <module>
----> 1 next(stacking())

<ipython-input-34-303528d26770> in stacking()
      4         first_block = arr3d[i,0]   # Initialize first_block
      5         first_block = (np.column_stack((first_block, arr3d[i,j])) for j in range(1,cols))
----> 6         final_arr = np.row_stack((final_arr, first_block))
      7     yield np.delete(final_arr, 0, axis=0)

<__array_function__ internals> in vstack(*args, **kwargs)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py in vstack(tup)
    281     if not isinstance(arrs, list):
    282         arrs = [arrs]
--> 283     return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 0)
    284 
    285 

<__array_function__ internals> in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 9 and the array at index 1 has size 1
```

Is there a way to use np.column_stack/np.row_stack together with generators?

I am basically trying to make this piece of code run faster and use less memory, as I am dealing with large arrays. If there is another way to tweak this piece of code to do this, please let me know! Many thanks.

Comment: The only thing you should do in a loop is list append.  All `stacking` is done once, outside the loop.

Comment: Generators only help if you feeding one list on to another and so forth.  They aren't useful when working with arrays.

Comment: Ok. Is there any other way I could optimise this code for speed and memory? Or is it optimal already?

Comment: So you start with a `final_arr = np.empty((1, cols*cols))` array - one row of junk.  Then add a bunch to it, and at the end `np.delete` that junk!  Why didn't you start with `np.empty((0, cols*cols))`?  Better yet start with `alist=[]`, append a bunch to it, and then `column_stack` the list.  `concatenate` and all the `stack` variations (except `np.append`) accept a list.  Take advantage of that!

Comment: Thanks for the tip on `np.empty((0, cols*cols))`! If I use `list=[]`, I wouldn't have the option to use `reshape()` on a list. This code is basically doing the Kronecker (tensor) product. I am trying to write my own code to do the Kronecker product because my understanding is that `np.kron()` is not written for parallel processing and minimizing memory

Comment: Let's step back a minute.  Do you understand the error message?  To use `concatenate` (or any of the `stack` functions that use it), you have to understand array dimensions; you can't be sloppy.  Also remember, when doing `x = np.concatenate((x, y))` that you are making a new array, copying values from both `x` and `y`.  If you do this in a loop, the size of that copy gets bigger and bigger.  There's no memory or time savings!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60383660/why-is-numpys-kron-so-fast/60386471#60386471

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj, the link was really helpful. The time savings in my code would be the Parallel step and the memory savings would be in the def-yield generator