# Kronnecker product on just two dimensions of 3 dimensional arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, linear-algebra

Suppose two matrices:

```
a = np.array([[1,2],
              [3,4]])
b = np.array([[5,6],
              [7,8]])
```

which would give Kronecker product `ab = np.kron(a,b)`:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  2,  4],
       [ 3,  4,  6,  8],
       [ 3,  6,  4,  8],
       [ 9, 12, 12, 16]])
```

Now suppose there are three copies of these matrices in two arrays, like this:

```
c = np.stack([a,a,a])
d = np.stack([b,b,b])
```

I want to compute the Kronecker product of `c` and `d` such that the output is a 3 index array corresponding to 3 copies of `ab`, i.e. with shape `(3,4,4)`. However, simply performing `kron(c,d)` outputs shape `(9,4,4)`, which has more entries than needed and cannot be reshaped appropriately. Could you please help understand how to do this?

Comment: Isn't that `kron(a,a)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
res=np.zeros((3,4,4))
res[:] = np.kron(a,b)
```

Should work, broadcasting the `kron` to  all 3 planes.

`kron` is specialized rearrangement of the outer product of `a` and `b`.  A (2,2,2,2) rearranged to (4,4).  I worked out the details in another post:

[Why is numpy's kron so fast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60383660/why-is-numpys-kron-so-fast)

Your (3,4,4) could be obtained from a (3,2,2,2,2), but it's not standard, so there isn't an out-of-the-box function.  You could try adapting my answer.

---

```
In [246]: a = np.array([[1,2],
     ...:               [3,4]])
     ...: b = np.array([[5,6],
     ...:               [7,8]])

In [249]: np.kron(a,b)
Out[249]: 
array([[ 5,  6, 10, 12],
       [ 7,  8, 14, 16],
       [15, 18, 20, 24],
       [21, 24, 28, 32]])
```

As I showed before, `kron` can be produced by applying a transpose and shape to an `outer` product.  We can use `einsum` for both the outer and transpose:

```
In [253]: np.einsum('ij,kl->ikjl',a,b)     # ikjl instead ijkl
Out[253]: 
array([[[[ 5,  6],
         [10, 12]],

        [[ 7,  8],
         [14, 16]]],


       [[[15, 18],
         [20, 24]],

        [[21, 24],
         [28, 32]]]])
In [254]: np.einsum('ij,kl->ikjl',a,b).reshape(4,4)
Out[254]: 
array([[ 5,  6, 10, 12],
       [ 7,  8, 14, 16],
       [15, 18, 20, 24],
       [21, 24, 28, 32]])
```

Generalizing that to arrays (3,2,2) shape, we can add an extra 'batch' dimension:

```
In [255]: c = np.stack([a,a,a])
     ...: d = np.stack([b,b,b])
In [256]: c
Out[256]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[1, 2],
        [3, 4]]])
In [257]: c.shape
Out[257]: (3, 2, 2)
In [258]: np.einsum('aij,akl->aikjl',c,d).reshape(3,4,4)
Out[258]: 
array([[[ 5,  6, 10, 12],
        [ 7,  8, 14, 16],
        [15, 18, 20, 24],
        [21, 24, 28, 32]],

       [[ 5,  6, 10, 12],
        [ 7,  8, 14, 16],
        [15, 18, 20, 24],
        [21, 24, 28, 32]],

       [[ 5,  6, 10, 12],
        [ 7,  8, 14, 16],
        [15, 18, 20, 24],
        [21, 24, 28, 32]]])
```

But if we know that `c` and `d` are just replications of `a` and `b`, the broadcasted solution is fastester

```
In [260]: res = np.zeros((3,4,4),int)
In [261]: res[:] = np.kron(a,b)
```

or even better (a view of the kron witout copies):

```
np.broadcast_to(np.kron(a,b),(3,4,4))
```

Some timings:

```
In [280]: timeit np.einsum('aij,akl->aikjl',c,d).reshape(3,4,4)
10.2 µs ± 22.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [281]: timeit res=np.zeros((3,4,4),int);res[:] = np.kron(a,b)
47.5 µs ± 1.66 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [282]: timeit np.broadcast_to(np.kron(a,b),(3,4,4))
57.6 µs ± 1.76 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [283]: timeit np.array(list(np.kron(x, y) for x, y in zip(c, d)))
143 µs ± 319 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

I'm bit surprised how much faster the `einsum` is. Also that `braodcast_to` isn't faster, though that's largely the fault of `kron` (which my previous answer showed was on the slow side).

Comment: Thanks. I still need to get more at ease with how the input to einsum works.

Answer (score 0):

This works, assuming you have no problem with the intermediate list (numpy needs the size before allocating the array):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2],
              [3, 4]])
b = np.array([[5, 6],
              [7, 8]])

c = np.stack([a, a, a])
d = np.stack([b, b, b])

result = np.array(list(np.kron(x, y) for x, y in zip(c, d)))

print(result)
print(result.shape)
```

Output:

```
[[[ 5  6 10 12]
  [ 7  8 14 16]
  [15 18 20 24]
  [21 24 28 32]]

 [[ 5  6 10 12]
  [ 7  8 14 16]
  [15 18 20 24]
  [21 24 28 32]]

 [[ 5  6 10 12]
  [ 7  8 14 16]
  [15 18 20 24]
  [21 24 28 32]]]
(3, 4, 4)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I would really prefer an all numpy solution though.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this would go like this

```
import numpy as np

def kron(a, b):

    ai = a[0]
    bi = b[0]

    b = np.asanyarray(b)
    a = np.array(a, copy=False, subok=True, ndmin=b.ndim)

    ndb, nda = bi.ndim, ai.ndim

    b_size = a.shape[0]

    as_ = ai.shape
    bs = bi.shape

    nd = ndb
    if (ndb != nda):
        if (ndb > nda):
            as_ = (1,) * (ndb - nda) + as_
        else:
            bs = (1,) * (nda - ndb) + bs
            nd = nda

    res = np.einsum("ij,ik->ijk", a.reshape((a.shape[0], -1)), b.reshape((b.shape[0], -1)))
    res = res.reshape((b_size, )+(as_ + bs))
    axis = nd - 1
    result = []
    for i in range(b_size):
        r = res[i]
        for _ in range(nd):
            r = np.concatenate(r, axis=axis)
        result.append(r)
    return np.array(result)

x = np.array([[1,2],
              [3,4]])
y = np.array([[5,6],
              [7,8]])

c = np.stack([x,x,x])
d = np.stack([y,y,y])

k = kron(c, d)
result = np.array(list(np.kron(x, y) for x, y in zip(c, d)))

print(np.allclose(k, result))
```

As @hpaulj mentioned in their answer, there is no built-in function to do this, and you would have to do some non-trivial reshape operation on the outer product to get this working.

The solution has been modified based on the implementation of [kron in numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.19.0/numpy/lib/shape_base.py#L1067-L1164).

I basically just added another outer loop on top of the loop that the numpy implementation is using to do the concatenation operation. This is meant to handle each outer product between the elements of `c` and `d` separately. Everything else is pretty much the same.

Note that this is not a generalisation of the kron implementation of numpy because this is **not** going to work for cases where you just want to do a straightforward `kron` operation. At least not without some additional modifications. I am also ignoring some edge cases that numpy is handling for clarity. However, this should work for your use-case.

Comment: `np.einsum('ijk,ilm->i????'c,d).reshape(3,4,4)` might work, but I'd have to work out the order of 'jklm'  in the ???? slot.  That is, einsum can both do the outer product and the transpose.

Comment: I tried doing that, but couldn't figure out how exactly to work that out. And since the numpy implementation is not doing this and instead concatenating the dimensions in a seperate for loop, I figured it might not be very straightforward at all.

Comment: I added a fast `einsum` solution to my answer.

Comment: @Ananda Thanks for your solution. I prefer the reassurance of using the einsum function though.