# How to measure the execution time for a classification algorithm in Python's scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

How do I measure the time taken to train and test a classifier like SVM, KNN and Decision Treen in scikit-learn?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to measure elapsed time in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/how-to-measure-elapsed-time-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `time` module like so

```
import time
start = time.time()

# enter your code here

end = time.time()
print(end - start, "seconds")
```

Comment: I found some suggestions to use timeit?