# Python - Easy execution timer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, timer

What is best way to check execution time?
I just use the `perf_counter` from time module.

```
from time import sleep, perf_counter

start = perf_counter()
sleep(1) 
finish = perf_counter()

if round(finish-start, 2) > 0:
    print(f"Finsished in {round(finish-start, 2)} (s)")
```

Comment: what do you mean by best?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to measure elapsed time in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/how-to-measure-elapsed-time-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Most people mean CPU time when they say "execution time" and for that you would use  `time.process_time()`. In your case, however, where all you are doing is sleeping between two consecutive calls, it would produce for the second call a return value of approximately 0. If you want elapsed time and are rounding to 2 places, I wouldn't think it would matter if you are using `time.time` or `time.perf_counter`. **But `perf_counter` provides the higher resolution when you do care about that.**

```
import time

t0 = time.time()
t0a = time.perf_counter()
t0b = time.process_time()
time.sleep(1)
t1 = time.time()
t1a = time.perf_counter()
t1b = time.process_time()
print(round(t1 - t0, 2), round(t1a - t0a, 2), t1b - t0b)
```

Prints:

```
1.0 1.0 0.015625
```