# How to change frameRate for a particular function (processing)

Tags: processing

I’m trying to implement a clock/timer. It works as of now but only problem is I need to make the frameRate to 1 but it affects the whole program’s frameRate. How do I change frameRate only for the clock function?

```
def clock():
global sec, minutes, hours, col
    
sec+=1
if(sec == 60):
    sec = 0
    minutes+=1
if(minutes == 60):
    minutes = 0
    hours+=1
if(hours == 24):
    hours = 0
    minutes = 0
    sec = 0
        
textSize(25)
fill(255, 0, 0)
text(floor(sec), 185, 110)
text(floor(minutes), 135, 110)
text(floor(hours), 85, 110)

if(sec % 2 == 0):
    col = color(0)
else:
    col = color(255, 0, 0)

fill(col)
textSize(30)
text(":", 120, 110)
text(":", 170, 110)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the frame rate only for one function because it doesn't make sense: The `draw()` function of processing is called in a loop at a defined frame rate (let's say that it's fixed at 60 times by second even thought in reality it can change). When you use the `frameRate()` function to change this value you change how fast the `draw()` function is called and since it is the one calling all your other functions you can't define that only for a specific function.

However you have other ways to achieve your clock/timer function:

First processing provides several time functions:

- [`millis()`](https://py.processing.org/reference/millis.html) returns the number of milliseconds since the program started. You could have you `clock()` function called by `draw()` make make it convert `millis()` to a number of seconds, minutes, hours, etc... This way you don't have to keep track of the time by yourself which will simplify your code a lot.
- Depending on what you want to do you can also access your computer clock with [`second()`](https://py.processing.org/reference/second.html), [`minute()`](https://py.processing.org/reference/minute.html) and all the functions in the "Time & Date" section [here](https://py.processing.org/reference/).

Secondly you could use the `time` module of python [as shown in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7370801/4194289) it's a bit of the equivalent of the `millis()` idea but with native python function.

Finally, still depending on your needs, you could want to have a look at python's Timer objects to execute your `clock()` function at a defined interval outside of the `draw()` loop, but while it is completely possible it is not straight forward and can be tricky for someone new to programming.