# How to calculate response time between elements in web page using Robot Framework selenium

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I have a browser where customer told to automate the test case of calculating the response time between elements when click and load time of it.
is there any keyword available ?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: its Python selenium robot framework ride

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to measure elapsed time in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/how-to-measure-elapsed-time-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best solution for that is to mesure accoding to Jmeter, it's not time that will come from code because there is difference between machine and machine , but on the API side there is no difference therefore the solution will be the Jmeter for example

Answer (score 0):

So [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/how-to-measure-elapsed-time-in-python) will possibly answer your question
Calculating response time is widely used technology, so you could just make simple google...
There are more other, different questions and tutorials about this

Comment: I was expecting some keyword from robot framework selenium??

Comment: There is no such method in robot framework since robot is designed for other purposes. In the same way you will not have in Selenium function to calculate velocity of your movements...