# python decorating recursive function

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm trying to use my timer_func decorator to log the process time of fibonacci function. But It seems like the decorator is logging multiple times:

```py
def timer_func(func):
    def inner_func(*args):
        t1 = perf_counter()
        res = func(*args)
        t2 = perf_counter()
        logging.log(logging.INFO, f"Done in {t2 - t1} Seconds!")
        return res

    return inner_func


@timer_func
def fibonacci(x: int):
    if x > 2:
        return fibonacci(x - 1) + fibonacci(x - 2)
    elif x == 1 or x == 2:
        return 1


r = timer_func(fibonacci)(5)
print("Fibonacci %d of is %d" % (5, r))
```

Output:

```
Done in 7.269991328939795e-07 Seconds!
Done in 7.840008038328961e-07 Seconds!
Done in 0.00013806700007990003 Seconds!
Done in 0.0006901449996803422 Seconds!
```

Comment: maybe because you are calling it multiple times?

Comment: also you are decorating twice

Comment: Create a wrapper function that does nothing but call the undecorated fib function and decorate the wrapper.

Comment: Is this an exercise? Because otherwise Python already has a decorator for timing functions. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/7370801/839733

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar It is. I don't wanna use that

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Which answer in that thread shows the decorator that you describe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The log will happen each time the `fibonacci` function is called.  Since the function is recursive, it is getting called multiple times.

You'll need to make a second version of the function that has the decorator and calls the non-decorated function.  For example:

```
@timer_func
def fibonacci(x: int):
    return _fibonacci(x)


def _fibonacci(x: int):
    if x > 2:
        return _fibonacci(x - 1) + _fibonacci(x - 2)
    elif x == 1 or x == 2:
        return 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Even after decorating the function with @ you are again decorating just

```
r = fibonacci(5)
```

will do.