# How do I pass the random list generated in the get_me_random_list() function in my main() function?

Tags: python

I am trying to generate 100 separate lists of 500 positive integers and run each algorithm on the 100 lists.
This is meant to represent a worst­-case analysis, so I am searching for an element I know will
not be in the lists (-1).

The main() function is meant to be used to print the results i.e. "Sequential Search took xx seconds to run, on average."

I have tried passing the get_me_random_list function as a parameter for the algorithm functions, but that was unsuccessful.

```
def main():
    sequential_search(a_list, -1)
    ordered_sequential_search(a_list, -1)
    binary_search_iterative(a_list, -1)
    binary_search_recursive(a_list, 1)

def get_me_random_list():
    a_list = []
    for i in range(100):
        a_list.append(random.sample(range(1,500), 100))
    return a_list

def sequential_search(a_list,item):
    start = time.time()
    pos = 0
    found = False

    while pos < len(a_list) and not found:
        if a_list[pos] == item:
            found = True
        else:
            pos = pos + 1
    end = time.time()
    return found
    print(f"Total runtime of the sequential search is {end - begin}")


def ordered_sequential_search(a_list,item):
    start = time.time()
    pos = 0
    found = False
    stop = False

    while pos < len(a_list) and not found and not stop:
        if a_list[pos] == item:
            found = True
        else:
            if a_list[pos] > item:
                stop = True
            else:
                pos = pos + 1
    end = time.time()
    return found
    print(f"Total runtime of the ordered sequential search is {end - begin}")


def binary_search_iterative(a_list,item):
    start = time.time()
    first = 0
    last = len(a_list) - 1
    found = False

    while first <= last and not found:
        midpoint = (first + last) // 2
        if a_list[midpoint] == item:
            found = True
        else:
            if item < a_list[midpoint]:
                last = midpoint - 1
            else:
                first = midpoint + 1
    end = time.time()
    return found
    print(f"Total runtime of the binary search iterative is {end - begin}")


def binary_search_recursive(a_list,item):
    start = time.time()
    if len(a_list) == 0:
        return False
    else:
        midpoint = len(a_list) // 2
    if a_list[midpoint] == item:
        return True
    else:
        if item < a_list[midpoint]:
            return binary_search(a_list[:midpoint], item)
        else:
            return binary_search(a_list[midpoint + 1:], item)
    end = time.time()
    return found
    print(f"Total runtime of the binary search recursive is {end - begin}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: 'get_me_random_list' Arrrrr

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest two solutions.

### Solution 1

Remove the `main()` function altogether, then in the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block, do:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    a_list = get_me_random_list()
    sequential_search(a_list, -1)
    ordered_sequential_search(a_list, -1)
    binary_search_iterative(a_list, -1)
    binary_search_recursive(a_list, 1)
```

### Solution 2

Alternatively, make it so that `main()` takes `a_list` as a parameter, then generate `a_list` in the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block and pass it to `main()`:

```py
def main(a_list):
   ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a_list = get_me_random_list()
    main(a_list)
```

### Notes

Note that there are other issues with your code that my answer does not attempt to fix. For instance, all your functions follow this pattern:

```py
    # rest of function body
    end = time.time()
    return found
    print(f"Total runtime of the binary search recursive is {end - begin}")
```

1. `return` tells Python to *immediately* return the value; the `print()` statement will never run
2. All your start times are called `start`, but you use `begin` in all your time differences (`{end - begin}`)
3. Your `binary_search_recursive` calls an undefined function, `binary_search`
4. You attempt illegal operations between lists and integers in every function because `a_list` is a multi-dimensional list (a list of lists of ints, specifically)

Was it intentional to make `a_list` a 2D array?

### Suggestions

I recommend learning about and using a [decorator function](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/#timing-functions) for timing your functions. If you're interested in more stringent, robust profiling however, `time.time()` doesn't really do a great job. It's okay for a decent approximation of your performance. I suggest reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/how-to-measure-elapsed-time-in-python), and looking at the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module, which is part of the standard library.