# Can't understand why algorithm work so fast

Tags: python, algorithm, wrapper, binary-search, linear-search

I’ve been trying to use parametrised decorators and time function for becnhmark binary search vs linear algorithms running time and I don't understand, why with list size == 100m binary search runs 0.000014 sec and linear search runs 4.904940 sec. Where is my mistake? Or is it a normal speed for modern cpus? A few hours ago I set list size to 1b and run script. My pc frozen on a few hours and I forced a reboot it.
PS My CPU is I5 9th Gen.

```
import time


def second_outer(*dargs, **dkwargs):
    def outer(func):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            print(*dargs, **dkwargs)
            start = time.time()
            func_result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            print('Call function %s with duration %f' % (func.__name__, time.time() - start))
            return func_result
        return inner
    return outer


arr = [i for i in range(1, 100000000)]


@second_outer('binary search')
def binary_search(arr, item):
    start = 0
    end = len(arr) - 1
    while start <= end:
        middle = (start + end) // 2
        guess = arr[middle]
        if guess == item:
            return middle
        elif guess > item:
            end = middle - 1
        else:
            start = middle + 1
    return None


@second_outer('linear search')
def linear_search(arr, item):
    start = 0
    end = len(arr)
    for i in range(start, end):
        if arr[i] == item:
            return i
    return None


print(binary_search(arr, arr[-1]))
print(linear_search(arr, arr[-1]))
```

Comment: You should use `timeit.default_timer` or `time.perf_counter` rather than `time.time` for this purpose; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25823885/12299000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary search runs on `log(n)` and linear search runs on `n`. That means that the first one only has to do `log(n)` iterations, and `log2(100000000) = 26.5754`. So you are basically comparing 27 iterations vs 100m.

Comment: Thanks. But i trying to calculate running time for each algorithm. And I saw a strange linear algorithm running time: <5sec for 100m list and >2hr for 1b list. Why it can be if in case of log(n) elapsed time must be x10(100m x10 = 1b)

Comment: @phaestos Perhaps your list of length 1 billion was exceeding the available system memory and going into [swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_paging#Unix_and_Unix-like_systems), which is much slower than RAM.

Comment: Thank you sir. You're absolutely right. My program with list==1b eats 26gb of ram and 13gb of swap. It's 99.3% of ram and 85% of swap. Before the reboot, there were much fewer free resources and this led to an out of memory and swap. And now I have result of algorithms running: Binary search: 0.076235 sec. Linear search: 519.089405 sec. Awesome difference! Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is no error in your code)

It simply finds a number in in 27 iterations

```
Call function binary_search with duration 0.000125
```

This is for 1B numbers. Probably you had an error a couple of hours ago when your PC froze

Comment: I understand. But can't understand why linear search ran over than 50 sec for 1b if it ran 4.9 sec with 100m?