# How to create a low impact timer

Tags: c++, python, c, shell, timer

I want to create a timer to run on an embedded system with as little impact as possible. I can choose to implement the timer in C, C++, bash or python. The error in the timer can be +/- a few seconds.

I'm tempted just to create a loop in a bash script using the 'sleep()' command and the '&' to start it in the background. However I'm worried/don't quite understand if this will be keeping the system active/awake if implemented this way.

If it is keeping the system active/awake, is it possible to create a timer that doesn't do that using C, C++, python or maybe another way with a bash script?

Comment: What kind of resolution do you need?

Comment: "I take most uses of the compound C/C++ as an indication of ignorance. " ~ Bjarne Stroustrup - See also http://www.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq.html#C-slash

Comment: If your embedded system runs python, surely the OS has timer functionality built-in?

Comment: @Griwes you dont shout to everyone how ignorant they are even if you did find some FAQ website, right?

Comment: @Ulterior, questions marked both [tag:c] and [tag:c++] are plague here, on SO...

Comment: It seems that your embedded system runs linux (or similar POSIX-compatible system). Does it run a cron task?

Comment: [`fcron`](http://fcron.free.fr/) should do what you want.

Comment: What is the goal of the timer?

Comment: I want the timer to allow me to read some data from a file on a consistent interval. This file will contain data on average current and CPU states. I want the timer to allow me to do this while affecting this data as minimally as possible. Unfortunately, cron is not available. C/C++ debate isn't relevant to the question, it's corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are worried about system resource or power consumption issue in an embedded system, you should definitely use RTC to implement timer.

Please refer to http://linux.die.net/man/4/rtc

And, check the user manual of the operating system you are using. Maybe there are some functions existing to call.

It is not necessary to reinvent the timer related functions.

Comment: RTC is limited to 8192Hz, and anything above 60Hz requires running as root. I've found that using [setitimer](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getitimer.html) to generate alarm signals at regular intervals is more portable, offers the possibility of microsecond granularity (depending on the implementation), and doesn't require any special privileges. Then you can simply call the pause() system call in a loop to sleep between alarm signals. Python even includes support for this method using the [signal module](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can do timers in a number of different ways.

The simplest is just something like

```
date "+%s"
```

Which prints out the timestamp of the system.  If the system clock is adequate, then getting two timestamps, one at the start and the second at the end, you can find the elapsed time by finding the difference in these two timestamps.

There are equivalent ways to do this on every language, C, C++, Python etc.

If you're timing a process that ends, you could do something like

```
TIC=$(date "+%s")
./some-script
TOC=$(date "+%s")
DELTA=$((TOC - TIC))
echo $DELTA
```

Or [alternatively in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465146/how-do-you-determine-a-processing-time-in-python).

In any case, I don't think your sleep idea is the best approach.

Comment: I think you misunderstand his question. He doesn't want to *measure* time, he wants to have a task run periodically.

Comment: If that is the case, its not very clear and then my answer wouldn't apply.

Comment: Thanks, this gave me some ideas but Rob is correct. I don't want to measure time but to have a task run periodically.