# How long would it take for a computer of x Mb RAM to calculate this calculation

Tags: scientific-computing, processing-efficiency

I was wondering about:

1. what are the aspects in a computer that affect how fast a program runs and executes
2. How can I calculate an estimate for the time it would take for a computer with x mb to run the program fully.

For example, how can I know how long it would take a computer to compute 
`2^44523432542352352342 - 1 Mod 447324523`(just random numbers)

According to `mersenne.org`, it says it can take up to weeks on very fast computers. So how are they able to compute such estimates of time?

Comment: What language are you using? This would differ on a very large amount of variables. You have to take into account, primarily, the speed of the processor. Then, depending on how precise you want to calculate this, the OS's processes for communicating with the processor and memory management may take some effect even if it's in the realm of nano-seconds.

Comment: I am using python. So I take there is no simple method for calculating such estimate even if it wasn't that accurate? (just a rough estimation)

Comment: I'd imagine there is a way, my point in mentioning those variables are to say this value returned will not be absolute and may vary if even by a few nano-seconds so being aware of this in the case of reporting it to a superior or a customer is important to note. As for how to calculate said value, I'm not sure but I'll return if and when I find something. Off to Wizard of Google, I mean Oz. ;)

Comment: Found a couple options here. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465146/how-do-you-determine-a-processing-time-in-python) is a question talking about the same issue and the documentation of [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) referenced in the answer.