# How to measure time taken between lines of code in python?

Tags: python, time, profiling, measure

So in Java, we can do [How to measure time taken by a function to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313893/how-to-measure-time-taken-by-a-function-to-execute)

But how is it done in python? To measure the time start and end time between lines of code?
Something that does this:

```
import some_time_library

starttime = some_time_library.some_module()
code_tobe_measured() 
endtime = some_time_library.some_module()

time_taken = endtime - starttime
```

Comment: There's a [good answer detailing the difference between time.process_time() / time.perf_counter() / time.time() and time.monotonic()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62115793/1026) in another question.

Answer (score 246, accepted):

If you want to measure CPU time, can use [`time.process_time()`](https://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.process_time) for Python 3.3 and above:

```
import time
start = time.process_time()
# your code here    
print(time.process_time() - start)
```

First call turns the timer on, and second call tells you how many seconds have elapsed.

There is also a function `time.clock()`, but it is [deprecated since Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.clock) and will be removed in Python 3.8.

There are better profiling tools like `timeit` and `profile`, however time.process_time() will measure the CPU time and this is what you're are asking about.

If you want to measure wall clock time instead, use `time.time()`.

Comment: This isn't how you use `time.clock()`, and `time.clock()` measures CPU time on Unix but wall time on Windows. It's better to use `time.time()` where behaviour doesn't vary with OS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85451/python-time-clock-vs-time-time-accuracy

Comment: Good observation, @Tim. However another post on the same question quotes python doc on time.clock() that "this is the function to use for benchmarking Python or timing algorithms". I guess it goes to the question of what you actually want to measure.

Comment: A very bad thing about time.time() is that it is affected by time sunchronization ntpdate etc. I would say time.clock() would be the only reliable alternative because of this

Comment: `DeprecationWarning: time.clock has been deprecated in Python 3.3 and will be removed from Python 3.8: use time.perf_counter or time.process_time instead`

Comment: @SundeepPidugu As the answer says, “tells you how many seconds have elapsed”

Comment: Hmmm... not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I replaced `# your code here` with `time.sleep(10)` and got 0.0 seconds.  Adding `for i in range(10000):/pass` produced the same results.  Under any circumstances I tried, `time.process_time()` always returns the same number.  I got expected results using `time.perf_counter()` though

Comment: Agreed with @biscuit314, the results I'm getting with `time.process_time()` are wildly inaccurate (i.e. getting 10x seconds than actually elapsed in the entire program), `time.perf_counter()` seems to be a lot more reliable

Comment: When I run the snippet in the response, I find that `time.process_time()` is always equal to `start` . Hence the time elapsed is always `zero`

Answer (score 90):

You can also use `time` library:

```
import time

start = time.time()

# your code

# end

print(f'Time: {time.time() - start}')
```

Comment: @Hayat - This method returns the time as a floating point number expressed in seconds since the epoch, in UTC. [https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html]

Comment: @AnumoySutradhar not really, since it's substracting an epoch from an epoch, you get the time difference between the two times.

Answer (score 46):

With a help of a small convenience class, you can **measure time spent in indented lines** like this:

```
with CodeTimer():
   line_to_measure()
   another_line()
   # etc...
```

Which will show the following after the indented line(s) finishes executing:

```
Code block took: x.xxx ms
```

**UPDATE:** You can now get the class with `pip install linetimer` and then `from linetimer import CodeTimer`. See [this GitHub project](https://github.com/justasb/linetimer).

The code for above class:

```
import timeit

class CodeTimer:
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = " '"  + name + "'" if name else ''

    def __enter__(self):
        self.start = timeit.default_timer()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.took = (timeit.default_timer() - self.start) * 1000.0
        print('Code block' + self.name + ' took: ' + str(self.took) + ' ms')
```

You could then **name the code blocks** you want to measure:

```
with CodeTimer('loop 1'):
   for i in range(100000):
      pass

with CodeTimer('loop 2'):
   for i in range(100000):
      pass

Code block 'loop 1' took: 4.991 ms
Code block 'loop 2' took: 3.666 ms
```

And **nest** them:

```
with CodeTimer('Outer'):
   for i in range(100000):
      pass

   with CodeTimer('Inner'):
      for i in range(100000):
         pass

   for i in range(100000):
      pass

Code block 'Inner' took: 2.382 ms
Code block 'Outer' took: 10.466 ms
```

Regarding `timeit.default_timer()`, it uses the best timer based on OS and Python version, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/85536/407108).

Answer (score 26):

Putting the code in a function, then using a decorator for timing is another option. ([Source](https://medium.com/better-programming/decorators-in-python-72a1d578eac4)) The advantage of this method is that you define timer once and use it with **a simple additional line** for every function.

First, define `timer` decorator:

```
import functools
import time

def timer(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.perf_counter()
        value = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.perf_counter()
        run_time = end_time - start_time
        print("Finished {} in {} secs".format(repr(func.__name__), round(run_time, 3)))
        return value

    return wrapper
```

Then, use the decorator while defining the function:

```
@timer
def doubled_and_add(num):
    res = sum([i*2 for i in range(num)])
    print("Result : {}".format(res))
```

Let's try:

```
doubled_and_add(100000)
doubled_and_add(1000000)
```

Output:

```
Result : 9999900000
Finished 'doubled_and_add' in 0.0119 secs
Result : 999999000000
Finished 'doubled_and_add' in 0.0897 secs
```

Note: I'm not sure why to use `time.perf_counter` instead of `time.time`. Comments are welcome.

Comment: This is awesome but... why is `functools` needed? Your code seems to work perfectly without it.

Comment: `functools.wraps` is used to make the `timer` function a decorator, just like how docs show: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps

Comment: Are you sure it works without the `@functools.wraps(func)` line?

Answer (score 19):

I always prefer to check time in hours, minutes and seconds (%H:%M:%S) format:

```
from datetime import datetime
start = datetime.now()
# your code
end = datetime.now()
time_taken = end - start
print('Time: ',time_taken)
```

output:

```
Time:  0:00:00.000019
```

Answer (score 7):

I was looking for a way how to output a formatted time with minimal code, so here is my solution. Many people use Pandas anyway, so in some cases this can save from additional library imports.

```
import pandas as pd
start = pd.Timestamp.now()
# code
print(pd.Timestamp.now()-start)
```

Output:

```
0 days 00:05:32.541600
```

I would recommend using this if time precision is not the most important, otherwise use `time` library:

`%timeit pd.Timestamp.now()` outputs 3.29 µs ± 214 ns per loop

`%timeit time.time()` outputs 154 ns ± 13.3 ns per loop

Answer (score 4):

You can try this as well:

```py
from time import perf_counter

t0 = perf_counter()

...

t1 = perf_counter()
time_taken = t1 - t0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the module `time`, we can calculate unix time at the start of the function and at the end of a function. Here is how the code might look like:

`from time import time as unix`

This code imports `time.time` which allows us to calculate unix time.

`from time import sleep`

This is not mandatory, but I am also importing `time.sleep` for one of the demonstrations.

`START_TIME = unix()`

This is what calculates unix time and puts it in a variable. Remember, the function unix is not an actual function. I imported `time.time` as unix, so if you did not put `as unix` in the first import, you will need to use `time.time()`.

After this, we put whichever function or code we want.
At the end of the code snippet we put

`TOTAL_TIME = unix()-START_TIME`

This line of code does two things: It calculates unix time at the end of the function, and using the variable `START_TIME` from before, we calculate the amount of time it took to execute the code snippet.

We can then use this variable wherever we want, including for a `print()` function.

`print("The snippet took {} seconds to execute".format(TOTAL_TIME))`

Here I wrote a quick demonstration code that has two experiments as a demonstration. (Fully commented)

```py
from time import time as unix # Import the module to measure unix time
from time import sleep

# Here are a few examples:
# 1. Counting to 100 000
START_TIME = unix()
for i in range(0, 100001):
  print("Number: {}\r".format(i), end="")
TOTAL_TIME = unix() - START_TIME
print("\nFinal time (Expirement 1): {} s\n".format(TOTAL_TIME))

# 2. Precision of sleep
for i in range(10):
  START_TIME = unix()
  sleep(0.1)
  TOTAL_TIME = unix() - START_TIME
  print("Sleep(0.1): Index: {}, Time: {} s".format(i,TOTAL_TIME))
```

Here was my output:

```
Number: 100000
Final time (Expirement 1): 16.666812419891357 s

Sleep(0.1): Index: 0, Time: 0.10014867782592773 s
Sleep(0.1): Index: 1, Time: 0.10016226768493652 s
Sleep(0.1): Index: 2, Time: 0.10202860832214355 s
Sleep(0.1): Index: 3, Time: 0.10015869140625 s
Sleep(0.1): Index: 4, Time: 0.10014724731445312 s
Sleep(0.1): Index: 5, Time: 0.10013675689697266 s
Sleep(0.1): Index: 6, Time: 0.10014677047729492 s
Sleep(0.1): Index: 7, Time: 0.1001439094543457 s
Sleep(0.1): Index: 8, Time: 0.10044598579406738 s
Sleep(0.1): Index: 9, Time: 0.10014700889587402 s
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `timeit` module to benchmark your performance:

```
def test():
    print("test")
    emptyFunction()
    for i in [x for x in range(10000)]:
        i**i


def emptyFunction():
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import timeit
    print(timeit.timeit("test()", number = 5, globals = globals()))
    #print(timeit.timeit("test()", setup = "from __main__ import test",
    #    number = 5))
```

the first parameter defines the piece of code which we want to execute `test` in this case & `number` defines how many times you want to repeat the **execution**.

### Output:

```
test
test
test
test
test
36.81822113099952
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html):

```
import timeit
timeit.timeit("code_tobe_measured()")
```

e.g.

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("import pandas")
2.923877900000008
```

Answer (score -1):

Let me add a little more to https://stackoverflow.com/a/63665115/7412781 solution.

- Removed dependency on `functools`.
- Used process time taken `time.process_time()` instead of absolute counter of `time.perf_counter()` because the process can be context switched out via kernel.
- Used the raw function pointer print to get the correct class name as well.

This is the decorator code.

```
import time

def decorator_time_taken(fnc):
    def inner(*args):
        start = time.process_time()
        ret = fnc(*args)
        end = time.process_time()
        print("{} took {} seconds".format(fnc, round((end - start), 6)))
        return ret
    return inner
```

This is the usage sample code. It's checking if 193939 is prime or not.

```
class PrimeBrute:
    @decorator_time_taken
    def isPrime(self, a):
        for i in range(a-2):
           if a % (i+2) == 0: return False
        return True

inst = PrimeBrute()
print(inst.isPrime(193939))
```

This is the output.

```
<function PrimeBrute.isPrime at 0x7fc0c6919ae8> took 0.015789 seconds
True
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It gives completely wrong timings, around 40% below the actual processing_time

Answer (score -2):

import datetime

#this code before computation

%%timeit
~code~

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).