# I'm got this function and it takes in the html code of wikipedia pages. It takes forever to run, any ideas how to make it more efficient?

Tags: python

> I'm got this function and it takes in the html code of wikipedia pages. It takes forever to run, any ideas how to make it more efficient?

```
def wikipedia_distribution(file, clean=True):
    with bz2.open(file, encoding="utf8", mode='rt') as source_file:
        data = source_file.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html')

        if clean == True:
            pages_text = [[item for item in page.get_text().split('\n') if item != ''] for page in pages]
        else:
            pages_text = [str(page).split('\n') for page in pages]
            
        print(2)
        # variable to save the results
        char_list = [len("".join(page)) for page in pages_text]
        print(3)
        lines_list = [len(page) for page in pages_text_clean]
        print(4)
        lines_lens = [len(line) for page in pages_text for line in page]
        print(5)
        return char_list, lines_list, lines_lens
```

Comment: first work out what the slow part actually is! Is it reading the file, processing it? THen you can spend time in those areas. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452145/how-to-measure-time-taken-between-lines-of-code-in-python

Comment: you have a few prints in your code, what parts are taking forever?

Comment: perhaps a SSD is the best way to speed up such a program

Comment: How many files are you processing?

Comment: Why isn't it using `soup`? Where do you set `pages`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I made some mistakes with the variables, after fixing these the issue seems to be resolved