# Inferencing slower on detectron2 when using multithreading with cv2.VideoCapture

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, opencv, pytorch

To start, this is a continuation of this question: [Multithreading degrades GPU performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69349555/multithreading-degrades-gpu-performance). However, since that question never got resolved due to everyone not being able to reproduce the results, I have created a new question with code here that reproduces the slower results outlined there.

To recap: when using `cv2.VideoCapture` with multi-threading, the inferencing time for Detectron2 is much slower compared to when multi-threading is disabled.

Some additional information is that I am operating on Windows and am using an RTX3070 so inferencing times may be slightly different for those trying to rerun this.

Here is the code:

```
import time
import cv2
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
from detectron2.config import get_cfg
from detectron2 import model_zoo
from detectron2.engine import DefaultPredictor


class FileVideoStream:
    def __init__(self, path, queueSize=15):
        self.stream = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
        self.stopped = False
        self.Q = Queue(maxsize=queueSize)

    def start(self):
        t = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        return self

    def update(self):
        while True:
            if self.stopped:
                self.stream.release()
                return
            if not self.Q.full():
                (grabbed, frame) = self.stream.read()
                if not grabbed:
                    self.stop()
                    return
                self.Q.put(frame)


cfg = get_cfg()
cfg.merge_from_file(model_zoo.get_config_file(
    "COCO-Detection/faster_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml")
)
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST = 0.7  # set threshold for this model
cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = model_zoo.get_checkpoint_url(
    "COCO-Detection/faster_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml"
)
cfg.MODEL.DEVICE = "cuda"
predictor = DefaultPredictor(cfg)


def threading_example():
    print("Threading Example:")
    fvs = FileVideoStream(r"DemoVideo.mp4")
    fvs.start()

    # allow time for thread to fill the queue
    time.sleep(1)

    for i in range(5):
        img = fvs.Q.get()
        start = time.time()
        p = predictor(img)
        end = time.time()
        print(f"Frame {i} Prediction: {(end - start):.2f}s")
    fvs.stopped = True


def non_threading_example():
    print("Non-Threading Example:")
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(r"DemoVideo.mp4")
    for i in range(5):
        _, img = video.read()
        start = time.time()
        p = predictor(img)
        end = time.time()
        print(f"Frame {i} Prediction: {(end - start):.2f}s")


non_threading_example()
threading_example()
```

This produces the following output:

```
Non-Threading Example:
Frame 0 Prediction: 1.41s
Frame 1 Prediction: 0.14s
Frame 2 Prediction: 0.14s
Frame 3 Prediction: 0.14s
Frame 4 Prediction: 0.14s
Threading Example:
Frame 0 Prediction: 10.55s
Frame 1 Prediction: 10.41s
Frame 2 Prediction: 10.77s
Frame 3 Prediction: 10.64s
Frame 4 Prediction: 10.27s
```

EDIT: I've added code to answer a comment about testing if the GPU on inferencing when inside a thread, which does not appear to be the case.

```
def infer_5(img):
    for i in range(5):
        start = time.time()
        p = predictor(img)
        end = time.time()
        print(f"Frame {i}: {(end - start):.2f}s")

def system_load():
    img = cv2.imread(
        r"Image.jpg")
    t = Thread(target=infer_5, args=(img,))
    t.start()
```

```
Frame 0: 7.51s
Frame 1: 0.39s
Frame 2: 0.15s
Frame 3: 0.15s
Frame 4: 0.15s
```

Comment: Can you try to replace p=predictor(img) by a simple sleep in both examples, to test whether the slow down has actually to do with the dnn-multithreading or whether it comes from your queue/synchronization?

Comment: smells to me like the *thread* lacks some setup that allows the net to run on the GPU... so it runs on the CPU instead. check system resource load (cpu, gpu) to test this hypothesis? -- strip the VideoCapture. just imread one picture once, then infer on that a few times, in the thread.

Comment: @Micka I changed the `p=predictor(img)` with `time.sleep(0.1)` and non-threading ran in 0.11s and the threading example ran in 0.13s (I assume the added time having to do with the FileVideoStream implementation)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I dont know python well or python threading at all, but I would think in the example, the `p = predictor(img)` runs in the main thread (same as in the non-threaded example?), while the video data generation is running in the additional thread?!?

Comment: @Micka that is correct, the prediction runs in the main thread while the image loading happens in the separate thread.

I've edited the question to test ChristophRackwitz's hypothesis. It appears that it is still using the GPU for inferencing from within the thread anyway.

Comment: One of the comments on the original post talked about how the python's GIL might be blocking certain parts of memory that the original thread needs to infer on the images in the other thread. Do either of you know if this is true or not?

Comment: @Micka right, good catch. inference still runs in the main thread. headache all day. -- the GIL shouldn't affect things here at all. those frames aren't touched by any multiple things at any point. -- you could try enqueueing **a copy** of the frame. that shouldn't do anything except cost some time. if that _does_ have an effect, that would be curious!