# Subtracting asctime from time module to get hours minutes and seconds in python

Tags: python

How can I subtract end - start to get hours minutes and seconds of time completion in Python?

I have some pseudocode here, I want to convert the print statement to what I said above.

```
start = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))

< some code here>

end = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))

print(end - start)
```

Comment: How does the posted code relate to your question?

Comment: Keep your `start` and `end` variable in epoch time and only a the end do something like `time.strftime("%H:%M:%S",time.localtime(end-start))`

Comment: I would use `time.gmtime` here to avoid timezone offsets being included.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to measure time taken between lines of code in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452145/how-to-measure-time-taken-between-lines-of-code-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

**a solution using `datetime`**

You can use the `datetime` module in Python to subtract two `datetime` objects and obtain a `timedelta` object that represents the duration between the two times. The `timedelta` object can be further used to extract hours, minutes, and seconds by accessing its attributes `total_seconds()`, `seconds`, `minutes`, `hours`, and `days`. Here is an example:

```
import datetime  

start = datetime.datetime.now()
end = datetime.datetime.now()

duration = end - start

hours, remainder = divmod(duration.total_seconds(), 3600)
minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
```