# Calculate exact time for page to load via Selenium WebDriver with python

Tags: python, selenium

I have a UI on which some pages are taking a time to load. I need to calculate the time for the page to load.
How this can be achieved.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [unitteset](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) module. 
Here is a [simple example](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#using-selenium-to-write-tests) that may achieve what you want.  You would probably have to write a test for each page to times specific to the page.

Another option is to use the `time` module and wrap around the call you'd like to time.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620943/measuring-elapsed-time-with-the-time-module) explains how to do that.

Comment: Thanks, let me rephrase my query.I have a test case in which I have to open a UI and from this when I clicked on some drop down then another page is opened now I have to calculate time that is taken to open  for this UI.

Comment: I don't think selenium has any built in feature for this, so the second part of my answer would probably be your best bet.