# Timer in a traffic light simulation

Tags: python, time, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, timeit

I'm currently working on a Python 3.x project and I'm supposed to make a simple crossroad simulation with traffic lights etc. My only problem right now is that I am not aware of any way to measure time so as to use it to change the traffic lights accordingly. Is there any way to create a virtual timer which will begin as soon as the simulation starts and goes on infinitely until the window is closed? I'm considering using the time or timeit modules, but I'm a bit lost here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Yes](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/time.html). You can first get the initial time with `time.time()` or `time.clock()` and use that to calculate the current simulation time by calling either of the two before the window closes

Comment: @pbreach Why not add this as an anser? It's far too good to be just a comment.

Comment: Because this is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-to-get-current-time-in-python), of a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/measure-time-elapsed-in-python), of a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620943/measuring-elapsed-time-with-the-time-module)... You get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys! I tried using both of them but the other answer below suits me better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you included the tag `tkinter`, there is a tkinter-specific solution that works quite well. You can use the `after` method available on every widget to schedule an event to happen in the future.

In the simplest case, you can have a function that will run some other function on a given interval. For example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def run_periodically(func, ms):
    func()
    root.after(ms, run_periodically, func, ms)

def tick():
    global count
    count += 1
    tick_label.configure(text="count: %d" % count)


count = 0
root = tk.Tk()
tick_label = tk.Label(root, text="")
tick_label.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

run_periodically(tick, 1000)

root.mainloop()
```

Of course, instead of having something called on a schedule, you can also just schedule the jobs as needed. For example, when the light turns red you can use `after` to both turn it off and turn the green on. You can then use `after` to turn the green off and the yellow on, and so on. Since this sounds like a homework assignment I won't provide an example.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I've been looking for!