# Python timed button push

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python 3.6 application that waits indefinitely for the user to push a button.

```
while(1)
    print('You have 10 seocnds to push the button and start the connection wizard')
    If if GPIO.input(button1)==0: 
        subprocess.call(["wifi", "--clear=ssid"])
```

However, I only want to allow **10 seconds to push the button** before moving on, how?

I have tried looping `(for loop)` but this just iterates and did not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Measuring elapsed time with the Time module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620943/measuring-elapsed-time-with-the-time-module)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a time delay in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510348/how-can-i-make-a-time-delay-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the time module to record the time before entering the loop, then calculate the time elapsed during each iteration. Add the time elapsed to the while condition.

```
import time

time_elapsed = 0
start_time = time.time()
while(time_elapsed < 10)
    print('You have 10 seocnds to push the button and start the connection wizard')
    If if GPIO.input(button1)==0: 
        subprocess.call(["wifi", "--clear=ssid"])
    time_elapsed = time.time() - start_time
```