# Measure time from one moment to another python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am coding a simple game in Python 3 and I need to measure the time passed from one moment to another. Ideally I would like a function that starts measuring and another one which returns the time passed. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Measuring elapsed time with the Time module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620943/measuring-elapsed-time-with-the-time-module)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Measure time elapsed in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/measure-time-elapsed-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

it's pretty simple, using the stdlib `time` module:

```
import time
t1 = time.time()
# other code ...
t_diff = time.time() - t1  # time in seconds
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful

Comment: Yeah, I'm using this all the time. Would you mind accepting the answer?