# Time actions in Python

Tags: python, timer

I want to run a part of my loop for a certain time: 60 seconds. Afterwards I set a boolean flag and continue at another point. Does Python have something like a stopwatch? Maybe this is OS specific: it's targeted against a Linux env.

Sleeping a couple of seconds is easy... no question. ;) I want the opposite.

Comment: you want a way to do this in Python or are you seeking an alternative to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [the `time.time()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.time):

```
import time
endtime = time.time() + 60
while time.time() < endtime:
    # do something
```

Note - you probably don't want to use `time.clock()` as [this measures CPU time rather than wall time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85451/python-time-clock-vs-time-time-accuracy).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`time.time()`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.time) to set the begin of the loop, and later check if the passed time is greater than 60 seconds. But then you'll have a problem if the clock changes during the loop (very rare case) - so you should check for negative differences, too.

```
import time

begin = time.time()

for something:
    # do something

    if not (begin <= time.time() <= begin + 60):
        break
```

As far as I know, Python does not include a stop watch class like in C#, for example.