# How do you calculate program run time in python?

Tags: python, time, runtime

How do you calculate program run time in python?

Comment: Good idea is this answer (short and quick):   
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1557584/3048464

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the `timeit` module:

http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html

or the `profile` module:

http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html

There are some additionally some nice tutorials here:

http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/profile/index.html

http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/timeit/index.html

And the `time` module also might come in handy, although I prefer the later two recommendations for benchmarking and profiling code performance:

http://docs.python.org/library/time.html

Comment: Thanks! This worked great. One note for others who may be using timeit for the first time, you will need to import locally defined symbols via timeit's setup parameter. For example (if myOwnFunc was locally defined and what you wanted to time): `print timeit.timeit('myOwnFunc()', setup='from __main__ import myOwnFunc', number=1)`. Without the setup parameter, it will complain that it could not find myOwnFunc.

Answer (score 350):

Quick alternative

```
import timeit

start = timeit.default_timer()

#Your statements here

stop = timeit.default_timer()

print('Time: ', stop - start)
```

Comment: @hajder the time it gives is in seconds right ?!

Comment: @diffracteD yes, UNIX EPOCH. http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.default_timer and
http://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: But default_timer() measures wall clock time, hence any other program will interfere with the measurement.

Answer (score 69):

I don't know if this is a faster alternative, but I have another solution -

```
from datetime import datetime
start=datetime.now()

#Statements

print datetime.now()-start
```

Comment: My favorite! Very simple, but I find that the final line should be 'print( datetime.now()-start )' and does not work without the parentheses.

Comment: @ThomasWinckelman: At the time I wrote the answer keeping Python 2 in mind.

Answer (score 6):

@JoshAdel covered a lot of it, but if you just want to time the execution of an entire script, you can run it under `time` on a unix-like system.

```
kotai:~ chmullig$ cat sleep.py 
import time

print "presleep"
time.sleep(10)
print "post sleep"
kotai:~ chmullig$ python sleep.py 
presleep
post sleep
kotai:~ chmullig$ time python sleep.py 
presleep
post sleep

real    0m10.035s
user    0m0.017s
sys 0m0.016s
kotai:~ chmullig$
```

Answer (score 4):

see this:
[Python - time.clock() vs. time.time() - accuracy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85451/python-time-clock-vs-time-time-accuracy)