# How to time execution time of a batch of code in Python?

Tags: python, time

I found this question and answer here on StackOverflow.

[Python - time.clock() vs. time.time() - accuracy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85451/python-time-clock-vs-time-time-accuracy)

Here is some code I'm trying to run:

```
import sys
import time
import timeit

if (len(sys.argv) > 1):
  folder_path = sys.argv[1]
  if not os.path.isdir(folder_path):
    print "The folder you provided doesn't exist"    
  else:
    print_console_headers()    
    rename_files_to_title_case(folder_path)
    #start the timer.
    #do some freaky magic here.
    #end the timer.

else:
  print "You must provide a path to a folder."

def print_console_headers():
  print "Renaming files..."
  print "--------------------"
  return

def rename_files_to_title_case():  
  """this is just for testing purposes"""  
  L = []
  for i in range(100):
      L.append(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from timeit import Timer
    t = Timer("test()", "from __main__ import test")
    print t.timeit()
```

How would I give timeit a function with a parameter that's been saved elsewhere?

This is something I've written in Ruby that gave me results in clean code, maybe this helps for suggestions.

```
start_time = Time.now

folder_path = ARGV[0]
i = 0
Dir.glob(folder_path + "/*").sort.each do |f|
    filename = File.basename(f, File.extname(f))
    File.rename(f, folder_path + "/" + filename.gsub(/\b\w/){$&.upcase} + File.extname(f))
    i += 1
end

puts "Renaming complete."
puts "The script renamed #{i} file(s) correctly."
puts "----------"
puts "Running time is #{Time.now - start_time} seconds"
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is how I typically write time measurement code in Python:

```
start_time = time.time()

# ... do stuff

end_time = time.time()
print("Elapsed time was %g seconds" % (end_time - start_time))
```

As mentioned in the post you linked to, `time.clock()` is not appropriate for measuring elapsed time since it reports the amount of CPU time used by *your* process only (at least on Unix systems). Using `time.time()` is cross-platform and reliable.

Comment: [`timeit` uses `time.clock()` on Windows](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/timeit.py#l70). `from timeit import default_timer as timer; start_time = timer(); ...` allows to switch between `time.time()` on *nix and `time.clock()` on Windows automatically or later It might use [`time.walltime()`](http://bugs.python.org/issue10278).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I don't think the OP is looking for the functionality of `time.clock()`, which is why I don't think `timeit` is an appropriate choice.

Comment: On Windows `time.clock()` measures walltime i.e., your remark: *"it reports the amount of CPU time used by your process only."* might be incorrect.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: That's true. I've clarified my answer.

Comment: Now *this* is a good answer, not that "Google it" elitist "answer" given before.

Answer (score 16):

I would use a timing decorator and place the code you want to time into a function.

```
import time

def timeit(f):

    def timed(*args, **kw):

        ts = time.time()
        result = f(*args, **kw)
        te = time.time()

        print 'func:%r args:[%r, %r] took: %2.4f sec' % \
          (f.__name__, args, kw, te-ts)
        return result

    return timed
```

Using the decorator is easy either use annotations.

```
@timeit
def compute_magic(n):
     #function definition
     #....
```

Or re-alias the function you want to time.

```
compute_magic = timeit(compute_magic)
```

My blog post here has more information. http://blog.mattalcock.com/2013/2/24/timing-python-code/

Answer (score 4):

A fun way to time functions is by using decorators and wrapper functions. One of the functions I use for this is:

```
import time

def print_timing(func):
    def wrapper(*arg):
        t1 = time.time()
        res = func(*arg)
        t2 = time.time()
        string = '| %s took %0.3f ms |' % (func.func_name, (t2-t1)*1000.0)
        print
        print '-'*len(string)
        print string
        print '-'*len(string)
        print
        return res
    return wrapper
```

Any function decorated by @print_timing, will print print the time it took to stdout

```
@print_timing
def some_function(text):
    print text
```

This makes it very convenient to time specific functions.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to measure a timing of specific lines of code within the function, when decorator can't help there is a solution

```py
import time
from time import sleep

class TT(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.start = time.time()
    def __str__(self):
        return str(time.time() - self.start)


timeit = TT()

sleep(1)
print timeit

sleep(2)
print timeit
```

will print:

```
1.0
3.00
```