# Display waiting time in text box using WXPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to make a application in which there are two buttons(say click & ok) and a text box.I want to generate waiting time between clicking on two buttons and display in text box.

**For Example:-**
If I first click on CLICK Button and wait for few seconds/minutes then click on OK Button. Then this waiting time should be displayed on text box.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? StackOverflow isn't a place to have people do your work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple to do with [Glade Interface Designer](http://glade.gnome.org/). 
`import time` then, create a variable `self.timer = None`.

Then when Click's `event` is raised simply state something like: `self.timer = time.time()`.

When OK's `event` is raised, write to the `TextBox`: `str((time.time()-self.timer))`.

This worked for me. If you aren't using glade, you can still use the same concept after you create your GUI.

---

See Also - [Python - time.clock() vs. time.time() - accuracy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85451/python-time-clock-vs-time-time-accuracy)

---

If you are asking how to code everything (including the GUI) in wxPython, I would suggest looking at some [tutorials](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started#A_First_Application:_.22Hello.2C_World.22) first.

Comment: @Priyank No problem, if this answers your question, please mark it as so.