# Converting Tkinter Event Time to System Time

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to see how recently an `Event` occurred (so that I can ignore the backlog of events that built up while a first event is being processed.) I see that events have a `time` attribute in milliseconds, but it doesn't line up with the system time I get from calling `time.time()`. Does anyone know how to convert between the two? Thanks!

### Example

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Label
from time import time

def print_fn(event): print event.time, time()

app = Tk()
label = Label(app, text='Click Here!')
label.bind('<Button>', print_fn)
label.pack()
app.mainloop()
```

### Output

```
1430467703 1360190553.41
```

Answer (score 1):

The *event.time* attribute would be useful for determining the time between two *Tkinter* events.

[*event.time*](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/event-handlers.html)

> This attribute is set to an integer which has no absolute meaning, but
>   is incremented every millisecond. This allows your application to
>   determine, for example, the length of time between two mouse clicks.

[*time.time*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html?highlight=time#time.time)

> Return the time in seconds since the epoch as a floating point number.
>   Note that even though the time is always returned as a floating point
>   number, not all systems provide time with a better precision than 1
>   second. While this function normally returns non-decreasing values, it
>   can return a lower value than a previous call if the system clock has
>   been set back between the two calls.

To measure how much time has elapsed we generally use [*time.time*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html?highlight=time#time.time) or [*time.clock*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html?highlight=time#time.clock) like this:

```
start = time.clock()
somefunction()
elapsed = time.clock() - start
```

You wouldn't have to use *event.time* at all.

More info about this can be found here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/85451/1217270)

Comment: I'm actually not trying to see how long it takes to run a function; I'm trying to roughly estimate the lag between the event and the corresponding function call. The lag can be quite long if a previous event invoked a function that takes a long time to execute; the recent event will sit in the Tkinter queue until the function call finishes. I find it problematic to let lots of events pile up, since the user may not realize they're invoking the time-consuming function many times.