# Fast and pythonic way to find out if a string is a palindrome

Tags: python, string, optimization, time-complexity

[Edit: as someone pointed out I have used improperly the palindrom concept, now I have edited with the correct functions. I have done also some optimizations in the first and third example, in which the for statement goes until it reach half of the string]

I have coded three different versions for a method which checks if a string is a palindrome. The method are implemented as extensions for the class "str"

The methods also convert the string to lowercase, and delete all the punctual and spaces. Which one is the better (faster, pythonic)?

Here are the methods:

1) This one is the first solution that I thought of:

```
    def palindrom(self):
        lowerself = re.sub("[ ,.;:?!]", "", self.lower())
        n = len(lowerself)
        for i in range(n//2):
            if lowerself[i] != lowerself[n-(i+1)]:
               return False
        return True
```

I think that this one is the more faster because there aren't transformations or reversing of the string, and the for statement breaks at the first different element, but I don't think it's an elegant and pythonic way to do so

2) In the second version I do a transformation with the solution founded here on stackoverflow (using advanced slicing string[::-1])

```
# more compact
def pythonicPalindrom(self):
    lowerself = re.sub("[ ,.;:?!]", "", self.lower())
    lowerReversed = lowerself[::-1]
    if lowerself == lowerReversed:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

But I think that the slicing and the comparision between the strings make this solution slower.

3) The thirds solution that I thought of, use an iterator:

```
# with iterator
def iteratorPalindrom(self):
    lowerself = re.sub("[ ,.;:?!]", "", self.lower())
    iteratorReverse = reversed(lowerself)
    for char in lowerself[0:len(lowerself)//2]:
        if next(iteratorReverse) != char:
            return False
    return True
```

which I think is way more elegant of the first solution, and more efficient of the second solution

Comment: hint : the `timeit` module is your friend when you want to compare differents implementations of a same feature.

Comment: Wait, I'm confused. Why would a palindrome-detecting function take two parameters? "is a palindrome" is a property of a single string, not of a pair of strings. "abcba" is a palindrome; ("abc", "cba") is not.

Comment: wrt/ pythonicity, implementing this as a method on `str` subclass is totally unpythonic - the pythonic way here would be to use a plain function.

Comment: @Kevin yeps I think what Nikaidoh means is "other is a reversed version of self" (spaces, punctuations and capitalization set aside).

Comment: Yes, @kevin, is as bruno says, now I'm going to edit

Comment: Another version with iterators: `all(map(operator.eq, lowerself, reversed(other)))`

Comment: I modified the functions as palindrome functions. 
I have done also some optimizations in the first and third example, in which the for statement goes until it reach half of the string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I decided to just `timeit`, and find which one was the fastest. Note that the final function is a cleaner version of your own `pythonicPalindrome`. It is defined as follows:

```
def palindrome(s, o):
    return re.sub("[ ,.;:?!]", "", s.lower()) == re.sub("[ ,.;:?!]", "", o.lower())[::-1]
```

#### Methodology

I ran 10 distinct tests per function. In each test run, the function was called 10000 times, with arguments `self="aabccccccbaa", other="aabccccccbaa"`. The results can be found below.

```
            palindrom       iteratorPalindrome      pythonicPalindrome      palindrome  
1           0.131656638            0.108762937             0.071676536      0.072031984
2           0.140950052            0.109713793             0.073781851      0.071860462
3           0.126966087            0.109586756             0.072349792      0.073776719
4           0.125113136            0.108729573             0.094633969      0.071474645
5           0.130878159            0.108602964             0.075770395      0.072455015
6           0.133569472            0.110276694             0.072811747      0.071764222
7           0.128642812            0.111065438             0.072170571      0.072285204
8           0.124896702            0.110218949             0.071898959      0.071841214
9           0.123841905            0.109278358             0.077430437      0.071747112
10          0.124083576            0.108184210             0.080211147      0.077391086

AVG         0.129059854            0.109441967             0.076273540      0.072662766
STDDEV      0.005387429            0.000901370             0.007030835      0.001781309
```

It would appear that the cleaner version of your `pythonicPalindrome` is marginally faster, but both functions clearly outclass the alternatives.

Comment: The whole point of a palindrome is that it compares to itself, why do you pass two strings into your function?

Comment: @MarkRansom before OP's edit, he did the exact same thing. I considered it.. unusual also, but I just rolled with it.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I have rewritten the function as palindrome function

Comment: I modified the functions as palindrome functions. I have done also some optimizations in the first and third example, in which the for statement goes until it reach half of the string

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to know the execution time of your blocks of code and compare them.

You can use the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module.

Here's a quick way:

```
import timeit

start = timeit.default_timer()

#Your code here

stop = timeit.default_timer()

print stop - start
```

> Read more:
>
> [Option 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707056/get-time-of-execution-of-a-block-of-code-in-python-2-7)
>
> [Option 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622976/how-do-you-calculate-program-run-time-in-python)

Comment: what is the difference between  datetime.datetime.now() and timeit.default_timer() besides resolution

Comment: The canonical way to use `timeit` is to either use it directly or to use it's `Timer` class... It repeats the code quite a few times so you get a meaningful average.

Answer (score 1):

You could also time this one-liner that does not use re, but itertools instead:

```
def isPalindrom(self):
    return all(i==j for i, j in itertools.zip_longest((i.lower() for i in self if i not in " ,.;:?!"), (j.lower() for j in self[::-1] if j not in " ,.;:?!")))
```

Or, explained in more details:

```
def isPalindrom(self):
    #using generators to not use memory
    stripped_self = (i.lower() for i in self if i not in " ,.;:?!")
    reversed_stripped_self = (j.lower() for j in self[::-1] if j not in " ,.;:?!")
    return all(self_char==reversed_char for self_char, reversed_char in itertools.zip_longest(stripped_self, reversed_stripped_self))
```

Comment: Not that you could also do `(i for i in self.lower() if i not in " ,.;:?!")`

Answer (score 1):

Recall that `filter` works on strings:

```
>>> st="One string, with punc. That also needs lowercase!"
>>> filter(lambda c: c not in " ,.;:?!", st.lower())
'onestringwithpuncthatalsoneedslowercase'
```

So your test can be a one liner that is obvious in function:

```
>>> str
'!esacrewol sdeen osla tahT .cnup htiw ,gnirts enO'
>>> filter(lambda c: c not in " ,.;:?!", st.lower())==filter(lambda c: c not in " ,.;:?!", str.lower()[::-1])
True
```

Or, if you are going to use a regex, just reverse the result with the idiomatic `str[::-1]`:

```
>>> "123"[::-1]
'321'
>>> re.sub(r'[ ,.;:?!]', '', st.lower())==re.sub(r'[ ,.;:?!]', '', str.lower())[::-1]
True
```

The *fastest* may be to use [string.tranlate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) to delete the characters:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.translate(st, None, " ,.;:?!")
'OnestringwithpuncThatalsoneedslowercase'
>>> string.translate(st, None, " ,.;:?!")==string.translate(str, None, " ,.;:?!")[::-1]
True
```

Answer (score 0):

When we pass a word it checks if it can be reversed,If it can be reversed it prints "This is a Palindrome". or "This is NOT a Palindrome"

```
def reverse(word):
    x = ''
    for i in range(len(word)):
        x += word[len(word)-1-i]
        return x

word = input('give me a word:\n')
x = reverse(word)
if x == word:
    print('This is a Palindrome')
else:
    print('This is NOT a Palindrome')
```

Comment: While this code may help the original poster it would be nice to elaborate your code so that it may be of help for future readers also.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a more pythonic way!

```
def palindrome_checker(string):
     string = string.lower()
     return string == string[::-1] # returns a boolean
```