# Python 's ( import time .. time.time() ) is not same as PHP's time(), this one has a dot

Tags: php, python, mod-wsgi, wsgi

In php

```
echo time();
```

and you get some 10 digit time stamp.

in python..

```
import time
>>> print time.time()
1374872354.62
```

where is the PHP's `time()` equivalence in Python ?

Comment: I don't have PHP installed. Can you add an example of what format you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so python's time() comes from the `time` module :)

which *may or may not* give the best time for your system:

time()

> "Return the time in seconds since the epoch as a floating point number. Note that even though the time is always returned as a
>   floating point number, not all systems provide time with a better
>   precision than 1 second. While this function normally returns
>   non-decreasing values, it can return a lower value than a previous
>   call if the system clock has been set back between the two calls." - [Python Time doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time)

sometimes clock() may work better:

> "On Unix, return the current processor time as a floating point number expressed in seconds. The precision, and in fact the very
>   definition of the meaning of “processor time”, depends on that of the
>   C function of the same name, but in any case, this is the function to
>   use for benchmarking Python or timing algorithms. - [Python Time doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time)
>       "

depending on your use you should choose one of these: for a discussion see here: [Python - time.clock() vs. time.time() - accuracy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85451/python-time-clock-vs-time-time-accuracy)

PHP time according to the docs does the following:

> "Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the
>   Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT). " -- [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)

So no matter which one you choose; you're most likely to get the same if not better resolution than PHP's time :)

If you want to time a function though, you should try the [`timeit`module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) which automatically chooses from either `clock` or `time` depending on the OS granularity

Comment: Although this is probably not the correct answer, i choose it because it looks like a-lot of effort was done to create this answer. - Sumer Kolcak

Comment: if you want higher precision in time for php use `microtime(true);` and get a float representation of the microseconds that have occured since the epoch. (which is 3 decimal places more precise then the millisecond measure shown in the example)

Comment: yup :). that is the most accurate way in PHP _assuming the hardware supports it_ "microtime() returns the current Unix timestamp with microseconds. This function is only available on operating systems that support the gettimeofday() system call." -- http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php ;)

Answer (score 1):

Python uses a float type so that it can represent fractional time. Just cast away that part:

```
>>> import time
>>> int(time.time())
1374872983
```