# Python time.clock() vs time.time() for timing a spawned process

Tags: python

I'm trying to time the execution of an external process that I'm calling from python. I wanted to time it and saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85451/python-time-clock-vs-time-time-accuracy) that time.clock() was the way to go. However I was seeing very inconsistent results with time.time(). I set up a simple example using time.sleep to mock the external process:

```
def t1(): 
  t0 = time.clock()
  time.sleep(2.5)
  return time.clock() - t0

def test_t1():
  timings = []
  for i in range(100):
    timings.append(t1())
  print sum(timings)/len(timings)
```

t2/test_t2 are similarly defined but use time.time() instead of time.clock()

```
>>>test_t1()
5.884e-05
>>>test_t2()
2.49959212065
```

Why would it be the case that time.clock is so wrong here?

EDIT: I should mention that I'm running this test on MacOSX and the deployed code will be running in Ubuntu

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/o0sqUOx.png

Comment: You should post the exact code you ran.  You didn't use this code ;-)  For example, as given, `t1()` returns `None`.

Comment: w00ps, sorry edited it to what I actually ran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time.clock()` returns computation time spent in the code; since `sleep` requires very little CPU it will not cost much `time.clock` time.

`time.time()` gets the actual real-life time difference, so will notice the sleep more readily.

Answer (score 0):

`time.clock()` is probably accurate, but isn't measuring wall-clock time.  On your box it's probably measuring CPU time.  Since your test program spends almost all its time sleeping (`time.sleep(2.5)`), it's accumulating very little CPU time.  `time.time()` is measuring wall-clock time, though.  [Read the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) for more ;-)