# What are the differences in Pythons time.clock() in Mac vs Windows?

Tags: python, macos, time

I am using Python's time to gauge the time frame of a Selenium process. My script is like this...

```
start_time = time.clock()
...
#ending with
final_time = '{0:.2f}'.format(time.clock()-start_time)
```

When ran on a windows OS I will get something like `55.22` but if ran on the Mac it will return something like `.14` even though it was about the same time.

Any idea what is happening differently on the Mac? I am actually going to try on Ubuntu as well to see the differences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.clock), `time.clock` is different between Unix (including Mac OS X) and Windows:

> On Unix, return the current processor time as a floating point number
>   expressed in seconds. The precision, and in fact the very definition
>   of the meaning of “processor time”, depends on that of the C function
>   of the same name, but in any case, this is the function to use for
>   benchmarking Python or timing algorithms.
>
> On Windows, this function returns wall-clock seconds elapsed since the
>   first call to this function, as a floating point number, based on the
>   Win32 function `QueryPerformanceCounter()`. The resolution is typically
>   better than one microsecond.

If you want cross-platform consistency, consider [`time.time`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time).

The difference between **processor time** and **wall-clock time** is explained in this [article by Doug Hellmann](http://pymotw.com/2/time/#processor-clock-time) - basically the processor clock is only advancing if your process is doing work.

Comment: Thank you, always a good idea to read the directions first, but that is not so fun ;-)

Comment: [use `timeit.default_timer()` that works across platforms and Python versions e.g., it uses `time.perf_counter()` when available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85451/python-time-clock-vs-time-time-accuracy#comment18341094_85536)

Answer (score 2):

The timeit module in the standard library uses `timeit.default_timer` to measure wall time:

```
if sys.platform == "win32":
    # On Windows, the best timer is time.clock()
    default_timer = time.clock
else:
    # On most other platforms the best timer is time.time()
    default_timer = time.time
```

`help(timeit)` explains:

> ```
> The difference in default timer function is because on Windows,
> clock() has microsecond granularity but time()'s granularity is 1/60th
> of a second; on Unix, clock() has 1/100th of a second granularity and
> time() is much more precise.  On either platform, the default timer
> functions measure wall clock time, not the CPU time.  This means that
> other processes running on the same computer may interfere with the
> timing.  The best thing to do when accurate timing is necessary is to
> repeat the timing a few times and use the best time.  The -r option is
> good for this; the default of 3 repetitions is probably enough in most
> cases.  On Unix, you can use clock() to measure CPU time.
> ```

So for cross-platform consistency you could use

```
import timeit
clock = timeit.default_timer

start_time = clock()
...
final_time = clock()
```

Comment: +1 for `timeit.default_timer()`. In Python 3.3+, `timeit.default_timer()` is `time.perf_counter()` on all platforms.