# counting the unique items in a numpy array: why is scipy.stats.itemfreq so slow?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to count the unique values in a numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
import scipy.stats
import time

x = np.tile([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],20000)
for i in [44,22,300,403,777,1009,800]:
    x[i] = 11

def getCounts(x):
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    for item in x:
        counts[item] += 1
    return counts

flist = [getCounts, scipy.stats.itemfreq]

for f in flist:
    print f
    t1 = time.time()
    y = f(x)
    t2 = time.time()
    print y
    print '%.5f sec' % (t2-t1)
```

I couldn't find a builtin function at first to do this, so I wrote `getCounts()`; then I found [`scipy.stats.itemfreq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.itemfreq.html) so thought I would use that instead. But it's slow! Here's what I get on my PC. Why is it so slow compared to such a simple handwritten function?

```
<function getCounts at 0x0000000013C78438>
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {1: 19998, 2: 20000, 3: 19999, 4: 19999, 5: 19999, 6: 20000, 7: 20000, 8: 19999, 9: 20000, 10: 19999, 11: 7})
0.04700 sec
<function itemfreq at 0x0000000013C5D208>
[[  1.00000000e+00   1.99980000e+04]
 [  2.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+04]
 [  3.00000000e+00   1.99990000e+04]
 [  4.00000000e+00   1.99990000e+04]
 [  5.00000000e+00   1.99990000e+04]
 [  6.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+04]
 [  7.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+04]
 [  8.00000000e+00   1.99990000e+04]
 [  9.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+04]
 [  1.00000000e+01   1.99990000e+04]
 [  1.10000000e+01   7.00000000e+00]]
2.04100 sec
```

Comment: There is a issue ticket on this function [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/599).  It looks like the maintainers had similar concerns about how it was written.  If you want to know why it was so slow, maybe check out [this commit](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/7e04d6630f229693cca3522b62aa16226f174053).  Depending on whether you're using a scipy version before or after this commit, you should be able to see how it is implemented.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you can use numpy 1.9, you can use `numpy.unique` with the argument `return_counts=True`.  I.e.

```
unique_items, counts = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)
```

In fact, `itemfreq` was updated to use `np.unique`, but scipy currently supports numpy versions back to 1.5, so it doesn't use the `return_counts` argument.

Here's the complete implementation of `itemfreq` in scipy 0.14:

```
def itemfreq(a):
    items, inv = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)
    freq = np.bincount(inv)
    return np.array([items, freq]).T
```

Comment: I never realized the speedup the numpy function has. Makes you wonder why it isn't used in the scipy function.

Comment: Actually I can just use `np.bincount` in my application since I have a large array of small integers.

Answer (score 3):

First, `time.time` is the wrong function to use when timing, as it measures wall-clock time, not cpu time (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85451/python-time-clock-vs-time-time-accuracy)). Ideally you would use the `timeit` module, but `time.clock` is also better.

Also, it seems that you might be using an outdated version of scipy. I'm using Python 3.4 and scipy 0.14.0 and these are my timings:

```
x = np.tile([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 20000)
for i in [44, 22, 300, 403, 777, 1009, 800]:
    x[i] = 11

%timeit getCounts(x)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 55.6 ms per loop

%timeit scipy.stats.itemfreq(x)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 20.8 ms per loop

%timeit collections.Counter(x)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 39.9 ms per loop

%timeit np.unique(x, return_counts=True)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 4.13 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

For the lazy:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.Series( my_list_or_array ).nunique()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. I can't use numpy 1.9 yet or scipy 0.14 because of some module conflicts in my application but looks like the new scipy.stats.itemfreq is much faster:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
import scipy.stats
import time
import timeit

x = np.tile([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],20000)
for i in [44,22,300,403,777,1009,800]:
    x[i] = 11

def getCounts(x):
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    for item in x:
        counts[item] += 1
    return counts

def itemfreq_scipy14(x):
    '''this is how itemfreq works in 0.14:
    https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/7e04d6630f229693cca3522b62aa16226f174053
    '''
    items, inv = np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)
    freq = np.bincount(inv)
    return np.array([items, freq]).T

flist = [getCounts, scipy.stats.itemfreq, np.bincount, itemfreq_scipy14, Counter]


for f in flist:
    print f
    print timeit.timeit(lambda: f(x),number=3)
```

which yields on my PC:

```
<function getCounts at 0x0000000013F8EB38>
0.148138969181
<function itemfreq at 0x0000000013C5D208>
6.15385023664
<built-in function bincount>
0.00313706656675
<function itemfreq_scipy14 at 0x0000000013F8EDD8>
0.0757223407165
<class 'collections.Counter'>
0.255281199559
```