# Timing a HTTP / database request: time.time() or time.clock()?

Tags: python, time, clock

I am interested in measuring the time elapsed during a (synchronous) HTTP request and/or a (synchronous) request to a database on a remote server. After reading this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85451/python-time-clock-vs-time-time-accuracy), my understanding is that `time.clock()` is an accurate measure of the processor time. But I don't know if "processor time" is relevant in my case, since the CPU would be idling while waiting for the response. In other words:

```
s0 = time.time()
# send a HTTP request
s1 = time.time()

t0 = time.clock()
# send a HTTP request
t1 = time.clock()
```

Which one actually measures what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For measuring HTTP response time, I think `time.time()` is enough.

As others suggested, use `timeit` if you want to do benchmarking.

I personally haven't used `time.clock()` before, but after reading the [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_clock.htm) :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time

def procedure():
    time.sleep(2.5)

# measure process time
t0 = time.clock()
procedure()
print time.clock() - t0, "seconds process time"

# measure wall time
t0 = time.time()
procedure()
print time.time() - t0, "seconds wall time"
```

I don't think `time.clock()` is appropriate measuring HTTP response time.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use [New Relic](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/python-agent/getting-started/new-relic-python) for python. You just install it and enable in application. After that, you will be able to see such charts in your New Relic account. It has a free plan.

[image: new relic charts]