# Python skip block of code if it take more then 2 second

Tags: python

I am new to python and I would like to ask if there is a way to skip a line of code in a python script if that line take more then a given time (like  for 2 second) ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85451/python-time-clock-vs-time-time-accuracy and use pass on your condition

Comment: How should the interpreter know how long it takes without running it?