# Python: time.clock() does not match real execution time

Tags: python, time, clock

I am testing the execution time of a python script. 
The script begins with

```
from time import clock
print clock()
```

and ends with

```
print clock()
```

My script executes much longer than the time difference I get with this method. I want to know why this happens? Is the processor time counted in a different way than I think?

Thanks for advice!

Comment: What are the durations you measures, and what did the clock return ? (out of curiosity)

Comment: You may want to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85451/python-time-clock-vs-time-time-accuracy

Comment: `time.clock()` should be the time your program ran in the CPU, so as a simple example, let's say you're opening a file, the I/O latency won't be reported by `time.clock()`. Also this function is deprecated from 3.3, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.clock

Comment: Thank you! I was the 'time.clock() is used for benchmarking' in the docs that confused me.

Comment: It is a simple sql select from a sqlit3 db it takes about 10 seconds on an old pentium 4 processcor machine and time.clock() says it were 1.3 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you need is real execution time rather than CPU time, use `time.time` instead of `time.clock`; also, you might be interested in `timeit` module.

Comment: For timing, the best to use is ``timeit.default_timer()``. This should map to whatever time function provides best time precision, plus when possible use a timer that isn't affected by changes in system time. That is, will use a monotonic timer.