# Why datetime.timedelta returns different values?

Tags: python-2.7

In the following code when I run following code why it returns me different time. It should be same.

```
`for i in range(2):
    start=time.time()
    print(start)
    a= np.arange(10).reshape(2,5)
    print(a)
    end=time.time()
    print(end)
    dd=datetime.timedelta(seconds = end-start)

    print("time diff: ",dd)`
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking for. Every OS that runs multiple processes has a scheduler that affects runtimes. Does this give you something to reword your question?

Comment: I want to ask that if i run for loop twice as in above code and suppose it takes 30 seconds for its completion .Then if I run it again it should take 30 seconds for its completion. dd value should be same for both case

Comment: No. It will not be the same. It will just be coincidence if they are the same. During those loop, some other processes could be taking turn in using the CPU. They don't get interrupted at the same exact moment for the same exact duration.

Comment: other processes? If I only run a single programe at a time

Comment: Are you telling me that your computer isn't running disk management, disk drivers, cron daemon, smtp, other linux services, etc.

Comment: by single programe I mean a single python programe

Comment: should I use time.clock to get the desired result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python's time.clock() vs. time.time() accuracy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85451/pythons-time-clock-vs-time-time-accuracy)

Answer (score 0):

### set priority on process the most times ill be ok there enjoy

```
import time 
import numpy as np
import datetime
import psutil, os
p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
p.nice(psutil.REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS)
for i in range(2):
    start=time.time()
    print(start)
    a= np.arange(10).reshape(2,5)
    print(a)
    end=time.time()
    print(end)
    dd=datetime.timedelta(seconds = end-start)
    print("time diff: ",dd)
```