# why calculating time difference returns error

Tags: python

I am trying to do the following to measure how long a function takes over a loop

```
a = datetime.datetime.now()
while x<1:
   callFunction()
   b = datetime.datetime.now()
   c = b-a  
   print(str(c))
```

But  I am getting this error

```
   c = b-a
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'float'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that your whole code?

Comment: And what is `callFunction` doing to `a`?

Comment: Nothing it has nothing to do with a. It does some image recognition stuffs

Comment: Actually your absolutly right.. ohh man  how did I not see it, I had a somewhere else in code...I should never work on Sunday

Comment: There some good ways out there to do this, I'm not talk about the error you got. Because it your value of `a` change somehow. Try other methods in this question [How do I get time of a Python program's execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1557571/6194097), you'll find some good methods from there as well as in this [Python's time.clock() vs. time.time() accuracy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/85451/6194097) question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `a` is assigned a `datetime` value and it later complains about it being a `float`, there's a very good chance that the `callFunction()` function is changing it.

I'd be looking into that as a first step.