# What does python time.clock() return?

Tags: python, time

Consider the following Python program that performs a lot of disk writing in a for loop:

```
from time import clock
import os
import sqlite3

data = sqlite3.connect('data.db')


t0 = clock()
with open("data.json") as f:
    for line in f:
        do some operations
        do some sqlite queries
        print(clock()-t0)
```

Why does the time displayed by `print(clock()-t0)` does not correspond to the real elapsed time ? It underestimates the elapsed time by a factor ~4.

Comment: What is displayed? What were you expecting? Note, it has dependent behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85451/pythons-time-clock-vs-time-time-accuracy

Comment: It will give the real time elapsed. What output are you getting?

Comment: It underestimates the elapsed time by a factor 4.

Comment: `time.clock` has been deprecated for years and was removed from Python 3.8. Check if you still have a problem using `time.perf_counter` or `time.process_time` (the suggested replacements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/time.html,

> **time.clock()**
> On Unix, return the current processor time as a floating point number expressed in seconds. The precision, and in fact
> the very definition of the meaning of “processor time”, depends on
> that of the C function of the same name, but in any case, this is the
> function to use for benchmarking Python or timing algorithms.
>
> On Windows, this function returns wall-clock seconds elapsed since the
> first call to this function, as a floating point number, based on the
> Win32 function QueryPerformanceCounter(). The resolution is typically
> better than one microsecond.

As you can see, it is platform-dependent. A better solution is to use datetime.now()

```
from datetime import datetime

t0 = datetime.now()
# ... do something ...
elapsed = datetime.now() - t0
```

Comment: Check `man clock` on the system in question.  It probably measures active processor time on Unix-likes, which means times not spent blocked on I/O.  It appears to be removed in recent versions of python.